# Regex to match a pattern, but exclude a set of words

Tags: regex

I have been looking through SO and although this question has been answered in one scenario:

[Regex to match all words except a given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242698/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list)

It's not quite what I'm looking for. I am trying to write a regular expression which matches any string of the form [\w]+[(], but which doesn't match the three strings "cat(", "dog(" and "sheep(" specifically.

I have been playing with lookahead and lookbehind, but I can't quite get there.  I may be overcomplicating this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

If the regular expression implementation supports [look-ahead or look-behind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could use the following:

- Using a negative look-ahead assertion:

  ```
   \b(?!(?:cat|dog|sheep)\()\w+\(
  ```
- Using a negative look-behind assertion:

  ```
   \b\w+\((?<!\b(?:cat|dog|sheep)\()
  ```

I added the `\b` anchor that marks a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). So `catdog(` would be matched although it contains `dog(`.

But while look-ahead assertions are more widely supported by regex implementations, the regex with the look-behind assertion is more efficient since it’s only tested if the preceding regex (in our case `\b\w+\(`) already did match. However the look-ahead assertion would be tested *before* the actual regex would match. So in our case the look-ahead assertion is tested whenever `\b` is matched.

Comment: The second one is most likely efficient since it doesn't check every single position with a negative look-ahead (it's worth noting that they're negative.) Also, I'm thinking it might be better to put the negative look-behind after the parenthesis and include a parenthesis in the look-behind. This way, it will only perform an extra look-behind once it finds a possible match, rather than for every word in the string.

Comment: Also, your first regex will reject `catastrophe(`, `dogmatic(` and `sheepily(`.  Your second one is saved from a similar error by the `\b` in the look-behind.

Comment: Right, I had a go with 

> grep '\b(?!(?:cat|dog|sheep))\w+[(]' text.txt 

text.txt
cat()
dog()
catdog()
something()

And it's not returning anything.  I also had a go in textmate with the regular expression search but nada.  I can see the logic behind the first statement though, perhaps this is a compatibility issue?  I thought look-ahead was pretty standard.  I've certainly been using it today in some form or another.

Comment: ah, no carriage returns, the second text.txt indicates the file's contents.

Comment: grep uses POSIX regular expressions, not PCRE, which are slightly different.  I don't think the POSIX standard includes lookbehinds or lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you, it was an unfortunate coincidence that both methods weren't working properly.  Textmate had copied over a carriage return into the regular expression search box.  Thanks very much for the help everyone

Comment: I have modifed the first one to "\b(?!cat\\(|dog\\(|sheep\\()\w+\\(" to prevent the problem mentioned by Rampion and that seems to work.  For some reason, it didn't like the word boundary in the second expression, so I changed it to a \W à la \b[A-Za-z]+\\((?<!\W(?:cat\\(|dog\\(|rat\\()) and that seems to have done the trick. Note that I had to change the third term to the same size as the others, fortunately this is not a problem.

Comment: The first regex just needed grouping parens around the alternation:  `\b(?!(?:cat|dog|sheep)\()\w+\(`

Answer (score 4):

Do you really require this in a single regex? If not, then the simplest implementation is just two regexes - one to check you don't match one of your forbidden words, and one to match your \w+, chained with a logical AND.