# Select only numeric part of a selection in a single regex

Tags: c#, regex

Well, I don't know how to explain that exactly, but I have this text:

`abc=0;def=2;abc=1;ghi=4;jkl=2`

The thing I want to do is select `abc=0` and `abc=1` but excluding `abc` part...

My regex is: `abc=\d+`, but it includes `abc` part...

I readed [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172873/regex-to-match-a-pattern-but-exclude-a-set-of-words) about this, and the answer was this: `(?!abc=)\d+` but It select all the numbers inside the text...

So, can somebody help me with this?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: I edited the tags, so, now you can know which language I'm using...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your language supports `\K` then you could use the below regex to matche the number which was  just after to the string `abc=`,

```
abc=\K\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/21)

OR

use a positive look-behind if your language didn't support `\K`,

```
(?<=abc=)\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/22)

C# code would be,

```
{
string str = "abc=0;def=2;abc=1;ghi=4;jkl=2";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=abc=)\d+");
 foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(str))
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hXDtxc)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=abc=)` Positive lookbehind which actually sets the matching marker just after to the string `abc=`.
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.

Comment: Oh, thanks you solve my question... I have to learn regex correctly! :P

Comment: @user3286975 added some info :-)

Comment: I readed something of this before, because I remembered that in the last part we have to use `(?=[\w+])` and in the first part `(?<=[\w+])`, why? :P Thanks for everything

Comment: `(?=)` is called positive look-behind. And `+` must be came just outside the character class so your regex would be `(?=[\w]+)` , `(?<=[\w]+)` .This pattern `(?=[\w+])` means follow up character must be a word character or a literal `+`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion here. You can simply use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture the matched context that you want and refer back to the matched group using the **Match**.[Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property.

```
abc=(\d+)
```

**Example**:

```
string s = "abc=0;def=2;abc=1;ghi=4;jkl=2";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"abc=(\d+)"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output**

```
0
1
```

Comment: +1, OP said C# which means either lookbehind or capture group, but not `\K` which is not supported in .NET.