# Replacing text in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a text using javascript and regex. Such that the words borex, edge and rss feeds get replaced with **borex**, **edge** and **rss feeds**.
The text appears like this.

```
<body>
<img src="http://some.web.site/image.jpg" title="borex" />
These words are highlighted: borex, edge, rss feeds while these words are not: bewedge, borexlumina, rss feedssss
</body>
```

Get replaced with:

```
<body>
<img src="http://some.web.site/image.jpg" title="borex" />
These words are highlighted: <b>borex</b>, <b>edge</b>, <b>rss feeds</b> while these words are not: bewedge, borexlumina, rss feedssss
</body>
```

I tried:

```
var str = document.getElementByTagName("body")
 str.replace(/borex/g,'<b>borex</b>').replace(/edge/g,'<b>edge</b>').replace(/rss feeds/,'<b>rss feeds</b>')
```

This gets all of them. How do i get only the word that is not part of another word? Any other suggestions are welcome.. Need some help...

Comment: Your `str` variable does not actually contain the string of text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\b` to indicate [a word boundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes#answer-1324756):

```
str.replace(/\b(borex|edge|rss feeds)\b/g, '<b>$1</b>');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ELaWZ/

Comment: just a qn: should it be $1 or \1 in the answer you gave?

Comment: @lakesh - Why would you want that to be `\1`?

Answer (score 3):

Use regex [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
str.replace(/\bborex\b/g,'<b>borex</b>').replace(/\bedge\b/g,'<b>edge</b>').replace(/\brss feeds\b/,'<b>rss feeds</b>')
```