# Regex to find whole words

Tags: java, regex

How would I find if a whole word, i.e. `"EU"`, exists within the String `"I am in the EU."`, while not also matching cases like `"I am in Europe."`?

Basically, I'd like some sort of regex for the word i.e. `"EU"` with non-alphabetical characters on either side.

Comment: Take a look at word boundaries \b

Answer (score 8):

`.*\bEU\b.*`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       String regex = ".*\\bEU\\b.*";
       String text = "EU is an acronym for  EUROPE";
       //String text = "EULA should not match";


       if(text.matches(regex)) {
           System.out.println("It matches");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Doesn't match");
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like

```
String str = "I am in the EU.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bEU\\b").matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found word EU");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a pattern with *word boundaries*:

```
String str = "I am in the EU.";

if (str.matches(".*\\bEU\\b.*"))
    doSomething();
```

Take a look at the [docs for `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, Java docs don't really tell what a word boundary is. This SO item digs deeper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes