# Check whether the whole string matches Java regular Expression using pattern

Tags: java

My logic is to find whether the file contains specific version text. For example the file may contain

```
act 1.9
ACT 1.4
MA 1.2
ma 1.9
...
```

I want to return true if my file contain any of the above text. Meaning the text to be searched in case Insensitive and the version may be anything from 0.0 to 9.0

So i wrote the regular expression as below:

```
    final Map<String, Float> outdatedPatterns = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    outdatedPatterns.put("act\\s*_*([0-9.]+)", Float.parseFloat("5.4"));
    outdatedPatterns.put("ma\\s*_*([0-9.]+)", Float.parseFloat("5.3"));

    for (Map.Entry entry : outdatedPatterns.entrySet()) {
        String regex = (String) entry.getKey();
        Float minSupportedVersion = (Float) entry.getValue();
        Pattern outdatedPattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher outdatedPatternMatcher = outdatedPattern.matcher(content);
        while (outdatedPatternMatcher.find()) {
            /* stuff  */
```

Problem with this logic is, the logic considers following texts also true

schema 1.4
react 3.0

But all i wanted is to search the whole string act and ma only.
Kindly suggest how to change my regular expression to solve the issue

Comment: Are `act 1.9 ACT 1.4 MA 1.2 ma 1.9` = `4 different words`?

Comment: yes they are seperate seperate words

Comment: Add a `\b` (boundary) to the front of the regex (e.g. `"\\bact\\s*_*([0-9.]+)"`)

Comment: "\bact\s*_*([0-9.]+)"   - yes this seems to be working. Thank you

Comment: also ... `Float.valueOf(5.4)` is cheaper than `Float.parseFloat("5.4")`

Comment: Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574853/regex-to-find-whole-words)

Comment: @tibrigaran Thanks for the info. The version i am getting from some other csv file as string. so i mentioned it as string in my example