# Detect URL in a string without any whitespace regexp

Tags: regex, url, detection

So I know the idea of catching any URL is a very difficult task, and that's not what i'm wanting to do. I'm wanting to find a piece of regex that'll catch urls in the form of

> http://something.xx.yy
>
> http://www.something.xxx
>
> www.something.xx.yy

in a string that will contain lots of other text and no whitespace, so for example

> hellopleasevisitwww.something.xxthankyou

I've tried my best to detect something like that by myself, but it's been pretty fruitless. Any help would be great. Below are some of the expressions I tried to modify in order to have these requirements met

```
.*\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|].*
\\b\\w*\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]\\w*\\b
\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it really can be as simple as you're saying...

```
(http://(www\\.)?|www\\.)[^.]+\\.(\\w{3}|\\w{2}\\.\\w{2})
```

The expressions you tried all have `\\b` which is a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes) and your string unfortunately does not have word boundaries.

Comment: Hey, i've tested it against some of the sample data I have and this is performing exactly as I needed it to. Thanks alot! :)