# Why do backslashes before braces make my regex match both <tr> and </tr>

Tags: regex, notepad++

In notepad++ I tried to make a regex to match `<tr>` tags. At first, I thought that sharp braces had to be escaped, so I tried `\<tr\>`. However, this matched not just the beginning tags as I would have expected, but all of the `<tr>`s (both `<tr>` and `</tr>`). Why is this?

Comment: These are slashes, not backslashes... Also, which language? Some languages treat the first character as a separator in regexes, and as such, the "pattern" part is "`<tr`", between the two `/` signs, and ther is a second part: "`>`" which would be the part to replace the matched pattern...

Comment: @ppeterka66 it was a typo, thanks. I'm not sure what regex processing Notepad++ uses. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\<` and `\>` mean "word boundary" in certain regex implementations, including Notepad++. From the [Notepad++ documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/?title=Regular_Expressions):

> `\<` This matches the start of a word using Scintilla's definitions of words.
>
> `\>`
>       This matches the end of a word using Scintilla's definition of words.

A word boundary is a zero-width match between a non-word character and a word character. Scintilla's [definition of "word character"](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) is:

> A word is defined to be a character string beginning and/or ending with the characters A-Z a-z 0-9 and _. Scintilla extends this definition by user setting. The word must also be preceded and/or followed by any character outside those mentioned.

Thus, your regex `\<tr\>` actually matches the word boundary between `<` (or `/`) and `t`, followed by `tr`, followed by the word boundary between `r` and `>`.

Comment: You sure `\>` has the same definition about word boundary?

Comment: To be precise, `\<` means non-word to word transition, and `\>` means word to non-word transition.

Comment: I mean the set of characters that is considered a word.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, I just amended the question. (Note that the "user setting" bit isn't really documented, but I guess it probably means locale-specific word characters can be added by the controlling application).

Comment: Nice. This is more a complete answer.

Comment: +1, but your last paragraph is a bit difficult to read, at first it looked wrong.

Answer (score 3):

- escaping needs backslashes, e.g. `\{`
- you don't need (shouldn't) escape `< or >`
- if you escaped them, it means word boundary, not only `<tr>, </tr>` but also `,tr,` will be matched

Comment: What's a word boundary. Thank you.

Comment: @thomas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes