# How to grep only words which consist of capital characters

Tags: regex, grep

I have problem write grep which should grep only those lines, in which is word that consist only from capital characters.

For example I have file : file1.txt

```
Abc AAA
ADFSD
F
AAAAx
```

And output should be :

```
Abc AAA
ADFSD
F
```

Thank for any advice.

Comment: Why is Abc part of the output?

Comment: Print line on which is some word that consist only from big letters.

Comment: Please read descriptions of tags before applying them, in particular those of "linux" and "unix", which simply don't belong here.

Answer (score 15):

You can just use:

```
grep -E '\b[[:upper:]]+\b' file1.txt
```

That is, look for whole words composed of only uppercase letters.

Answer (score 10):

This egrep should work:

```
egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' file
```

Comment: This don't work when `file` contains capitalize word having `_`(e.g.  `HELLO_WORLD`)

Comment: `_` is not considered a word boundary so `HELLO_WORLD` is not really a word that consists of only capital letters.

Comment: I think `_` is in word boundary, but not meaningful word boundary. If I am wrong, then you can give me a reference so that I can learn something new. Thank you for giving interesting information.

Comment: See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes

Comment: There they say **...with a word character ([0-9A-Za-z_])**. Thank you, very much for such a link. This idea is new to me.

Answer (score 3):

This will produce the desired results,

```
egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b'  file1.txt
```

Results are

```
Abc AAA
ADFSD
F
```

Comment: The `[^ ]*` would seem to permit mixedCASE?

Comment: Yeah this would allow mixed case; if you just want capitals and underscores, I may suggest `grep -w '\([_]*[A-Z]\+\)\+' file1.txt;`

Comment: (And to allow unlimited underscores out front: 
`grep -w '[_]*[A-Z]\+[A-Z_]*' file1.txt`)

Comment: @awalllllll you are right, my original answer did allow mixed case.

Comment: @tripleee, sorry, I was wrong and the answer was updated

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep supports POSIX patterns, so you can simply do:

`grep -e '[[:upper:]]' file1.txt`

Comment: Huh? This will find uppercase anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your input contains non-ASCII characters, you may want to use `\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]`:

```
grep -P '\b\p{Lu}+\b' file
```

For

```
LONDON 
Paris
MÜNCHEN Berlin
```

this will return

```
LONDON
MÜNCHEN Berlin
```

You can probably list most of these things manually, and as @Skippy-le-grand-gourou says, egrep extends `[A-Z]` to accented letters, but by using `\p{Lu}`, you do not need to deal with things like ["Since June 2017, however, capital ẞ is accepted as an alternative in the all-caps style"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Exceptional_letters_and_digraphs)

Comment: +1 for the working alternative, but FWIW anubhava's answer with `egrep` correctly displays and triggers on accentuated characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oP '\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b' file1.txt
```

This results words consisting of uppercase/digit/_ (e.g. `HELLO`, `NUMBER10`, `RLIMIT_DATA`).

But, this also accept `eDw`.

Answer (score 0):

grep '\<[A-Z]*>'  file1.txt

Comment: this do nothing.