# Regex for "might" begin with, but "must" follow with

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this must be super simple but ...trying to match 2 use cases:

it can match this (exact)

`var re = new RegExp("\\b" + name + "\\b");`

or match this (same as above but MUST start with a space)

`var re = new RegExp("^ \\b" + name + "\\b");`

---

Actually the problem is that the string can contain multiple entries seperated by spaces like this

```
" somevar1 somevar2 somevar3 "
```

So when we pass `name` to the regex above we want it to match either `at the beginning of the string with a space` or `at the beginning without space` ..when we are not matching the beginning of the string (the rest), we do not test for a leading space

basically this `"^ \\b" + name + "\\b|\\b" + name + "\\b"`

Comment: Shouldn't the first regex work for both cases?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you want to match (without mentioning any regex)

Comment: Just put the "^ " inside "(^ )?" to make it optional.

Comment: Please add examples of what you match. We can't help you if you don't.

Comment: Examples, please, examples for what you are trying to do!

Comment: updated with better samples

Comment: @Robert I still think you are overcomplicating this, as \b matches what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes/1324784#1324784. Also if you trim your input string you won't have any whitespace at the start for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use this pattern:

```
new RegExp("(?:^ |\\b)" + name + "\\b");
```

details:

```
(?:       # non capturing group
    ^[ ]  # start of the string followed by a space
  |       # OR
    \\b   # word boundary
)         # close the non capturing group
```

Here you have the choice between the start of the string with a space and a word boundary (that can be, for example `.name` or `#name` or `name`)

with `" ?\\b" + name`, since the space is optional, you can have `name` at the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks but i got my code mixed up ! :) What works for my particular code is actually ``" ?\\b" + name + "\\b"`` but ``"\s?\\b" + name + "\\b"`` does not ..what's the difference ? i thought \s is space ?

Comment: thanks again for the details. however isn't ``"\s?\\b" + name + "\\b"`` the same as ``" ?\\b" + name + "\\b"``. I'd say yes, but in my code they both behave differently

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your first regex does not work for both cases. But I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
"(^ )?\\b" + name + "\\b"
```

Comment: Why do you put `^ ` inside parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, the white space is in my comment but it's not very visible.

Comment: Ah sorry. Wrapped both in paranthesis to make them optional together. Might want to change it to `(?:^ )?` to hide it from the result.

Comment: No, it's me, I haven't understood your idea, but now it's ok. Indeed you could use non-capturing group, but it isn't essential.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need something like this:

```
new RegExp("^ ?\\b" + name + "\\b");
```

or like this:

```
new RegExp("^ *\\b" + name + "\\b");
```