# what does `\\s` mean in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with regular expression:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + clsName + '(\\s|$)');
```

What does `(^|\\s)` mean? Isn't it equal to `(^|\s)`, what does `(^|)` mean?

Am I right, it means that the string should start with any letter or white space? I tried to test with browser and console.log but still can't get any solution.

In all tutorials `\s` is used to be a space pattern not `\\s`.

Ok i got it, the problem was:

*When using the RegExp constructor: for each backslash in your regular expression, you have to type `\\` in the RegExp constructor. (In JavaScript strings, `\\` represents a single backslash!) For example, the following regular expressions match all leading and trailing whitespaces (\s); note that `\\s` is passed as part of the first argument of the RegExp constructor:*

```
re = /^\s+|\s+$/g
re = new RegExp('^\\s+|\\s+$','g')
```

Answer (score 2):

`(^|\\s)` means: Start of the string (`^`) OR (`|`) a space `\\s`.

If `clsName` is `"abc"`, for example, it builds the pattern `(^|\\s)abc(\\s|$)`. That searches for `"abc"` at the start, middle, or end of the string, and it may be surrounded by spaces, so these are valid:

- `"abc"`
- `"abc x"`
- `"x abc"`
- `"x abc y"`

Note that here you are using a string to build a RegExp. JavaScript ignores escape characters it doesn't know - `'\s'` would be the same as `'s'`, which isn't right.

Another option is to use [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1324676/7586), but might fail on some case (for example, searching for `btn` would match for `btn-primary`):

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + clsName + '\\b');
```

I'd also warn that `clsName` *might* contain regex meta-characters, so you may want to [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/7586).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just split the string on " "?

```
var string = 'abc defh ij klm';
var elements = string.split(' ');
var clsName = 'abc';
elements.filter(function (el) {
    return el === clsName;
});
```

No need for a RegEx like the one you posted.