# Extracting top-level and second-level domain from a URL using regex

Tags: regex, url, dns

How can I extract only top-level and second-level domain from a URL using regex? I want to skip all lower level domains. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

**Here's my idea,**

Match anything that isn't a dot, three times, from the end of the line using the `$` anchor.

The last match from the end of the string should be optional to allow for `.com.au` or `.co.nz` type of domains.

Both the last and second last matches will only match 2-3 characters, so that it doesn't confuse it with a second-level domain name.

---

**Regex:**

`[^.]*\.[^.]{2,3}(?:\.[^.]{2,3})?$`

---

**Demonstration:**

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/fX1fI5/2)

Comment: what about top level domains like "police.uk" or "parliament.uk" etc. More about .uk domains it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk

Comment: This regex is good for only domain url and fails for full length url. Ex: "www.google.com.bd/abc" will return "com.bd/abc"

Comment: This will also now fail for any new TLDs like .computer or .business.

Comment: This also doesn't work for 3 letter domain names like www.rgj.com or account.app.com...

Comment: The domain zone might be more than 3 letter, i.e. ".agency"

Comment: Globally it is bad nawadays to focus on numbers of letters for tld, sld, domain, scheme, host and path.
It didn't match complexe as https://subdomain.sld.tld/folder_domain.

Comment: downvoted for reasons above. Use the Publix Suffix List https://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 17):

### Updated 2019

This is an old question, and the challenge here is a lot more complicated as we start adding new vanity TLDs and more ccTLD second level domains (e.g. `.co.uk`, `.org.uk`). So much so, that a regular expression is almost guaranteed to return false positives or negatives.

The only way to reliably get the primary host is to call out to a service that knows about them, like the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/).

There are several open-source libraries out there that you can use, like [psl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psl), or you can write your own.

Usage for `psl` is quite intuitive. From their docs:

```
var psl = require('psl');

// Parse domain without subdomain
var parsed = psl.parse('google.com');
console.log(parsed.tld); // 'com'
console.log(parsed.sld); // 'google'
console.log(parsed.domain); // 'google.com'
console.log(parsed.subdomain); // null

// Parse domain with subdomain
var parsed = psl.parse('www.google.com');
console.log(parsed.tld); // 'com'
console.log(parsed.sld); // 'google'
console.log(parsed.domain); // 'google.com'
console.log(parsed.subdomain); // 'www'

// Parse domain with nested subdomains
var parsed = psl.parse('a.b.c.d.foo.com');
console.log(parsed.tld); // 'com'
console.log(parsed.sld); // 'foo'
console.log(parsed.domain); // 'foo.com'
console.log(parsed.subdomain); // 'a.b.c.d'
```

---

**Old answer**

You could use this:

```
(\w+\.\w+)$
```

Without more details (a sample file, the language you're using), it's hard to discern exactly whether this will work.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/wD8eP2

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can likely do that with some expression similar to,

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:w{3}\.)?.*?([^.\r\n\/]+\.)([^.\r\n\/]+\.[^.\r\n\/]{2,6}(?:\.[^.\r\n\/]{2,6})?).*$
```

and add as much as capturing groups that you want to capture the components of a URL.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jdw8bg/1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jdw8bg/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jdw8bg/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't match `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173734/extracting-top-level-and-second-level-domain-from-a-url-using-regex`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using JavaScript and wanting a simple way to extract the top and second level domains, I ended up doing this:

```
'example.aus.com'.match(/\.\w{2,3}\b/g).join('')
```

This matches anything with a period followed by two or three characters and then a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/726766).

Here's some example outputs:

```
'example.aus.com'       // .aus.com
'example.austin.com'    // .austin.com
'example.aus.com/howdy' // .aus.com
'example.co.uk/howdy'   // .co.uk
```

Some people might need something a bit cleverer, but this was enough for me with my particular dataset.

**Edit**

I've realised there are actually quite a few second-level domains which are longer than 3 characters (and allowed). So, again for simplicity, I just removed the character counting element of my regex:

```
'example.aus.com'.match(/\.\w*\b/g).join('')
```

Comment: The OP asked to exclude any lower level domains, e.g. lowerlevel.domain.co.uk using your example gives '.domain.co.uk'. Also doesn't handle URL starting with http:// or http://

Answer (score 0):

Since TLDs now include things with more than three-characters like .wang and .travel, here's a regex that satisfies these new TLDs:

`([^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+)$`

Strategy: starting at the end of the string, look for one or more characters that aren't periods or whitespace, followed by a single period, followed by one or more characters that aren't periods or whitespace.

http://regexr.com/3bmb3

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on two-part TLDs such as https://www.google.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

With capturing groups you can achieve some magix.

For example, consider the following javascript:

```js
let hostname = 'test.something.else.be';
let domain = hostname.replace(/^.+\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/, '$1');

document.write(domain);
```

This will result in a string containing `'else.com'`. This is because the regex itself will match the complete string and the capturing group will be mapped to `$1`. So it replaces the complete string `'test.something.else.com'` with `'$1'` which is actually `'else.com'`.

The regex isn't pretty and can probably be made more dynamic with things like `{3}` for defining how many levels deep you want to look for subdomains, but this is just an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all specific Top Level Domain name then you can write regular expression like this:

```
[RegularExpression("^(https?:\\/\\/)?(([\\w]+)?\\.?(\\w+\\.((za|zappos|zara|zero|zip|zippo|zm|zone|zuerich|zw))))\\/?$", ErrorMessage = "Is not a valid fully-qualified URL.")]
```

You can also put more domain name from this link:

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/tlds-2012-02-25-en

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches a domain with root and tld extractions (named capture groups) from a url or domain string:

```
(?:\w+:\/{2})?(?<cs_domain>(?<cs_domain_sub>(?:[\w\-]+\.)*?)(?<cs_domain_root>[\w\-]+(?<cs_domain_tld>(?:\.\w{2})?(?:\.\w{2,3}|\.xn-+\w+|\.site|\.club))))\|
```

It's hard to say if it is perfect, but it works on all the test data sets that I have put it against including .club, .xn-1234, .co.uk, and other odd endings.  And it does it in 5556 steps against 40k chars of logs, so the efficiency seems reasonable too.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to be more specific:

```
/\.(?:nl|se|no|es|milru|fr|es|uk|ca|de|jp|au|us|ch|it|io|org|com|net|int|edu|mil|arpa)/
```

Based on http://www.seobythesea.com/2006/01/googles-most-popular-and-least-popular-top-level-domains/

Comment: References a very old article (10 years old at time of writing). There are dozens more TLDs now. This could mislead readers to think this is a complete list

Comment: @Digs You are right, I'm still looking for the full list of TLDs

Comment: That's a nearly impossible task with new generic TLDs coming out all the time. .christmas, .london, .bar, .bank? See https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/announcements-and-media/case-studies Probably best to use one of the regex's mentioned in the other answers (eg.: `\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2,3})?`)