# In Java, how do I extract the domain of a URL?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, subdomain

I'm using Java 8.  I want to extract the domain portion of a URL.  Just in case I'm using the word "domain" incorrectly, what i want is if my server name is

```
test.javabits.com
```

I want to extract "javabits.com".  Similarly, if my server name is

```
firstpart.secondpart.lastpart.org
```

I want to extract "lastpart.org".  I tried the below

```
final String domain = request.getServerName().replaceAll(".*\\.(?=.*\\.)", "");
```

but its not extracting the domain properly.  Then I tried what this guy has in his site -- https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/domain-name-regular-expression-example/, e.g.

```
private static final String DOMAIN_NAME_PATTERN = "^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$";
```

but that is also not extracting what I want.  How can I extract the domain name portion properly?

Comment: What about `google.co.uk` and similar?

Comment: Suppose it will help you :)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173734/extracting-top-level-and-second-level-domain-from-a-url-using-regex

Comment: Just did some research on the whole `co.uk` thing and there appears to be a lot of other suffixes https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

Comment: *not extracting what I want.* you will need to detail things a little more, as it seems simple when you think naively about it and all simple solutions based on regex on splitting at dot may horribly fail. Like @LennartDeters look at the PSL. You may or may not need to use it depending on what you want to extract exactly. There is no automated way to do the same (the list change over time and is not believed to be exhaustive nor without errors there are **tons** of NXDOMAINs in it now)

Comment: Also the regex is completely wrong, it will not work for IDNs, whose labels are `xn--something`. Some TLDs are IDNs.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: *Do not use regex for this. Use whois.*

If I try to extrapolate from your question, to find out what you really want to do, I guess you want to find the domain belonging to some non-infrastructural owner from the host part of a URL. Additionally, from the tag of your question, you want to do it with the help of a regex.

The task you are undertaking is at best impractical, but probably impossible.

There are a number of corner cases that you would have to weed out. Apart from the list of infrastructural domains kindly provided by Lennart in https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat, you also have the cases of an empty host field in the URL or an IP-address forming the host part.

So, is there a better approach to this? Of course there is. What you do want to do is  query a public database for the data you need. The protocol for such queries is called [WHOIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS).

Apache Commons provide an easy way to access WHOIS information in the [WhoisClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/whois/WhoisClient.html).  From there you can query the domain field, and find some more information that may be useful to you.

It shouldn't be harder than

```
import org.apache.commons.net.whois.WhoisClient;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CommonsTest {
    public static void main(String args) {
        WhoisClient c = new WhoisClient();
        try {
            c.connect(WhoisClient.DEFAULT_HOST);
            System.out.println(c.query(URL));
            c.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Using this will get you the whois information aboutt he domain you are asking for. If the domain is uregistered, that is, is a private domain, as in the case of `www.stackexchange.com` you will get an error saying no domain is registered. Remove the first part of the address and try again. Once you found the registered domain, you will also find the registrar and the registrer.

Now, unfortunately, whois is not as simple as one would think. Read further on https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/whois/whois.1.en.html for an elaboration on how to use it and what information you can expect from different sources.

Also, check related questions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=whoisclient)

Comment: @YCF_L Yes, I did.

Comment: can I know the reason?

Comment: @YCF_L Of course. As I argue in my answer (above), this problem is not solvable with regex. Rather, there is an established solution for this kind of problem available through the internet infrastructure. As such, I downvoted the other answers because they are wrong, and will not work.

Comment: Merci! good answer as well You have my up-vote, I would like from you to share a real code example, this can be more helpful +1 from me ;)

Comment: @YCF_L Thank you! Good point with code example - I'll try to provide one within the day.

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
String parts[] = longDomain.split("."); 
String domain = parts[parts.length-2] + "." + [parts.length -1];
```

Comment: You should probably use a computation based on parts.length rather than use '1' and '2'

Comment: ```google.co.uk```

it will return ```co.uk``` .So it's not an domain