# Extract domain from url using PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, url

I need to extract the domain name for a list of urls using PostgreSQL. In the first version, I tried using REGEXP_REPLACE to replace unwanted characters like www., biz., sports., etc. to get the domain name.

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(url, ^((www|www2|www3|static1|biz|health|travel|property|edu|world|newmedia|digital|ent|staging|cpelection|dev|m-staging|m|maa|cdnnews|testing|cdnpuc|shipping|sports|life|static01|cdn|dev1|ad|backends|avm|displayvideo|tand|static03|subscriptionv3|mdev|beta)\.)?', '') AS "Domain", 
 COUNT(DISTINCT(user)) AS "Unique Users"
 FROM db
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This seems unfavorable as the query needs to be constantly updated for list of unwanted words.

I did try https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174423/10174021 to extract from the end of the line using PostgreSQL REGEXP_SUBSTR but, I'm getting blank rows in return. Is there a more better way of doing this?

A dataset sample to try with:

```
 CREATE TABLE sample (
 url VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO sample url) 
 VALUES 
 ("sample.co.uk"),
 ("www.sample.co.uk"),
 ("www3.sample.co.uk"),
 ("biz.sample.co.uk"),
 ("digital.testing.sam.co"),
 ("sam.co"),
 ("m.sam.co");
```

Desired output

```
+------------------------+--------------+
|    url                 |  domain      |
+------------------------+--------------+
| sample.co.uk           | sample.co.uk |
| www.sample.co.uk       | sample.co.uk |
| www3.sample.co.uk      | sample.co.uk |
| biz.sample.co.uk       | sample.co.uk |
| digital.testing.sam.co | sam.co       |
| sam.co                 | sam.co       |
| m.sam.co               | sam.co       |
+------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you make a list of "doubled TLDs" like co.uk?

Comment: Meaning? You want me to create more variation of doubled TLDs in the sample data?

Comment: No not in the sample data, that's OK as far as I'm concerned. But a possible solution I could imagine would match the end of the DNS names. But that may give you just co.uk instead of sample.co.uk. So these "doubled TLDs" need a special handling. That's why I as if you can make a list of them. After all the computer cannot "know" that co.uk is actually to be treated as *one* TLD.

Comment: This is exactly where I got stuck. The TLDs could either be .co.uk, .co or .uk.

Comment: One option may be to store all tlds in another table  with a hierarchy and use that to extract only the required part of the URL giving preference of extraction based on that priority.

Comment: This is far more complicated than it probably seems at first glance (I've tried to do it in the past).  Take a look at some of the python libraries (tld or tldextract) that do this.  They generally start with the full list of tlds available here: https://publicsuffix.org/list/ . It's quite long...

Comment: Thank you for this. It is very helpful. It covers all the different TLDs in my original dataset. I have to incorporate the Python library into my SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I've found the solution using Jeremy and Rémy Baron's answer.

1. Extract all the public suffix from [public suffix](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) and store into
   a table which I labelled as tlds.
2. Get the unique urls in the dataset and match to its TLD. [image: part1]
3. Extract the domain name using regexp_replace (used in this query) or alternative `regexp_substr(t1.url, '([a-z]+)(.)'||t1."tld")`. The final output: [image: final_output]

The SQL query is as below:

```
WITH stored_tld AS(
SELECT 
DISTINCT(s.url),
FIRST_VALUE(t.domain) over (PARTITION BY s.url ORDER BY length(t.domain) DESC
                            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS "tld" 
FROM sample s 
JOIN tlds t 
ON (s.url like '%%'||domain))

SELECT 
t1.url,
CASE WHEN t1."tld" IS NULL THEN t1.url ELSE regexp_replace(t1.url,'(.*\.)((.[a-z]*).*'||replace(t1."tld",'.','\.')||')','\2') 
END AS "extracted_domain" 
FROM(
    SELECT a.url,st."tld"
    FROM sample a
    LEFT JOIN stored_tld st
    ON a.url = st.url
    )t1
```

Links to try: [SQL Tester](https://sqltest.net/#573813)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
with tlds as (
     select * from (values('.co.uk'),('.co'),('.uk')) a(tld)
) ,
sample as (
    select * from (values ('sample.co.uk'),
                          ('www.sample.co.uk'),
                          ('www3.sample.co.uk'),
                          ('biz.sample.co.uk'),
                          ('digital.testing.sam.co'),
                          ('sam.co'),
                          ('m.sam.co')
                   ) a(url)
     ) 
  select url,regexp_replace(url,'(.*\.)(.*'||replace(tld,'.','\.')||')','\2') "domain" from (
            select distinct url,first_value(tld) over (PARTITION BY url order by length(tld) DESC) tld 
               from sample join tlds on (url like '%'||tld) 
         ) a
```

Answer (score 1):

I use **split_part(url,'/',3)** for this :

```
select split_part('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019744', '/', 3) ;
```

output

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: If you want to remove the "www." `select regexp_replace(split_part('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019744', '/', 3),'^www\.','');`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (a little bit more complex)

```sql
WITH
fqdn AS (
    SELECT
        row_number() over () as id,
        url,
        FQDN(url) AS "fqdn"
    FROM urls
),
stored_tld AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        id,
        url,
        tld,
        fqdn
    FROM fqdn
    LEFT JOIN tlds
           ON reverse(fqdn(url)) LIKE 
              replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '%') || '.%' COLLATE "C"
    ORDER BY id, -- for correct distinct on
             tld LIKE '%*%' DESC, -- prefer tld with wildcard
             length(tld) DESC -- prefer longer tld
),  extrated_domain AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        url,
        fqdn,
        reverse(
                substring(
                        reverse(fqdn), 
                        '#"' || replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '[^.]*') || '.[^.]*#"(.%|)', 
                        '#'
                )
        ) AS "extracted_domain"
    FROM stored_tld
)
SELECT
    url,
    fqdn,
    coalesce(extracted_domain, fqdn) AS "domain",
    extracted_domain IS NOT NULL AS "extracted"
FROM extrated_domain
```

Fiddle with comments : https://dbfiddle.uk/QSDKx2-t

### FQDN extracting

In order to extract [FQDN](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/fqdn) from a url, you can use a more complex regexp https://regex101.com/r/vT9k3d/2

```sql
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)/igm
```

Also, you can store this regexp as function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fqdn(url TEXT)
  RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE sql
  IMMUTABLE
  STRICT
AS $function$
select (regexp_matches(url, '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)', 'i'))[1]
$function$;
```

### Save row order

There are can be duplicates, especially, after extracting domains. Better to save order using row_number() over ()

```sql
SELECT
    row_number() over () as id,
    url,
    (regexp_matches(url, '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)', 'i'))[1] AS "fqdn"
FROM urls
```

### Pattern matching

First, we need to match all patterns for this domain

```sql
fqdn LIKE '%.' || replace(lower(tld), '*', '%') COLLATE "C"
```

or, better yet, use reversed strings to speed up the process later using [indexes with prefix matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/21920723)

```sql
reverse(fqdn) LIKE replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '%') || '.%' COLLATE "C"
```

### Result ranking

For extracting the best-match tld order rules should be used

```sql
ORDER BY id, -- for correct distinct on
         tld LIKE '%*%' DESC, -- prefer tld with wildcard
         length(tld) DESC -- prefer longer tld
```

### Extracting domain with suffix name without subdomain

We will use [substing postgresql function and pattern-matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

After some experiments I found out, that this works for me (for reverse suffix `abc.def`)

```sql
select substring('db.abc.def.fsdfsd', '#"db.[a-z0-9]*.[a-z0-9]*#"(.%|)', '#');
select substring('db.abc.def', '#"db.[a-z0-9]*.[a-z0-9]*#"(.%|)', '#');
```

the resulting extract is

```sql
reverse(
        substring(
                reverse(fqdn), 
                '#"' || replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '[^.]*') || '.[^.]*#"(.%|)', 
                '#'
        )
) AS "extracted_domain"
```

### Merging results

On the final step, we add `coalesce` for domains, that weren't found and add a flag to monitor if the domain was extracted or not.

```
SELECT
    url,
    fqdn,
    coalesce(extracted_domain, fqdn) AS "domain",
    extracted_domain IS NOT NULL AS "extracted"
FROM extrated_domain
```

Fiddle with comments: https://dbfiddle.uk/QSDKx2-t

Answer (score 0):

### Improve performance

In my case, I need to extract domain from 1M+ urls.

First of all, I cached columns, to speed up the calculations

```sql
/* LIKE column and index */

alter table tlds
add tld_like text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '%') || '.%') STORED;

/* Create pattern column */

alter table tlds
add tld_pattern text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  '#"' || replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '[^.]*') || '.[^.]*#"(.%|)' 
) STORED;
```

Then I added index for [prefix matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY tlds_like_idx
ON tlds (tld_like COLLATE "C");
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Prefix matching working on the reverse order. You should add such index on domain table. It my case, it isn't possible.

#### Profiling

Also, using profiling I found out, that LEFT JOIN generates 1M x 10k tdls = 10B rows in memory and do filter with 99.99% rows excluding

```sql
LEFT JOIN tlds
           ON reverse(fqdn(url)) LIKE 
              replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '%') || '.%' COLLATE "C"
```

#### Dirty hack

There are no top-level domains with less than 2 letters! So we can use 3 letters of domain ending as filter key! And index will be used!

```sql
alter table tlds
add tld_3l text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    left(replace(lower(reverse(tld)), '*', '') || '.', 3)
) STORED;

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY tlds_3l_idx
ON tlds (tld_3l COLLATE "C");
```

Final query:

```sql
WITH
fqdn AS (
    SELECT
        row_number() over () as id,
        url,
        fqdn(url) AS "fqdn",
        left(reverse(fqdn(url)), 3) as "f3l",
        reverse(fqdn(url)) as "rev_fqdn"
    FROM technical.domains_sample_test
),
stored_tld AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
        id,
        url,
        fqdn,
        tld,
        tld_like,
        tld_pattern
    FROM fqdn
    LEFT JOIN technical.webisite_tlds
           ON f3l = tld_3l 
          AND rev_fqdn LIKE tld_like COLLATE "C"

    ORDER BY id, 
             tld LIKE '%*%' DESC, -- prefer tld with wildcard
             length(tld) DESC -- prefer longer tld
),  extrated_domain AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        url,
        fqdn,
        reverse(substring(reverse(fqdn), '#"' || replace(tld_pattern, '%', '[^.]*#"(.%|)'), '#')) AS "extracted_domain"
    FROM stored_tld
)
SELECT
    url,
    fqdn,
    coalesce(extracted_domain, fqdn) AS "domain",
    extracted_domain IS NOT NULL AS "extracted"
FROM extrated_domain
```

New fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/GLcG6lQo