# Remove Sub string from large text file

Tags: python, linux, performance, substring

I am using Cisco umbrella top 1 million. I found that it includes a lot of sub domains. 
**google.com alone contains 2400+ domains.** I want to remove sub domains from Cisco umbrella top 1 million and want to see how many domains are left in the file

Is there any bash command which removes sub strings, i.e if the input file contains

```
google.com
play.google.com 
drive.google.com
```

the result should be like

```
google.com
```

Secondly, I tried following python code. It took a lot of time as it checks every domain against 1 million domains

```
import csv
domain_list=[]
import json
with open("~/Downloads/1/top-1m.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        domain_list.append(row[1])
multiple_domain=dict()
count=0
total_iter_json=0

for domain in domain_list:
    count=count+1
    print(count)
    res = [i for i in domain_list if '.'+domain in i] 
    if(len(res)>1):
        result=[]
        result.append(len(res))
        result.extend(res)
        multiple_domain[domain]=result
```

What can I do?

Comment: You might be interrested in this question : [Extracting top-level and second-level domain from a URL using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173734/extracting-top-level-and-second-level-domain-from-a-url-using-regex)

Comment: @Lescurel Let me cross check 
By the way thanks for time

Comment: For the replacement, the `sed` command in bash should do the work (and is quite fast already). For the second part, I strongly advise you to use the python module called `pandas` as is design to be more user-friendly and faster to compute dataframes than plain python loops. Is it ok for you to use it?

Comment: Jerome Richard That totally Make Sense Pandas is great option i will try that
Secondly @Lescurel thanks also for your input its solve 95 % problem