# Java String check

Tags: java, string, if-statement

i am checking whether "of" available in a sentence or not.I am trying to do a check on java String. page is a String variable and the code is here

```
page="Paint, Body & Trim : Body : Moldings : Sunroof";



if(page.contains("of"))
{
}
else
{
}
```

the problem in the above example sunroof has "of" so the loop give true. but i dont want words with "of" to be taken . please help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Scanner` with `" : "` delimiter:

```
String page="Paint, Body & Trim : Body : Moldings : Sunroof";

boolean contains(Scanner scan, word){
    scan.useDelimiter(" : ");
    while(in.hasNext())
        if(in.next().equals(word) return true;
    return false;
}
```

and then make a call like this `System.out.println(contains(new Scanner(page), "of");`

This is print `false`

Answer (score 4):

Just change this

```
if(page.contains("of"))
```

to

```
if(page.contains(" of "))
```

**EDIT**: Just to consider if the sentence starts or finishes with "of":

```
if(page.contains(" of ") || page.startsWith("of ") || page.endsWith(" of"))
```

Comment: this will fail if "of" is at start of string i.e no string at start.

Comment: This will fail if "of" is before a punctuation sign.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed How come will it return true Sunroof and" as page.startsWith("of ")??

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in this way. use `equals()` instead of `contains()`

```
String page="Paint, Body & Trim : Body : Moldings : Sunroof";
  for (String i:page.split(" ")){
        if("of".equals(i)){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `if(page.contains(" of "))` that way it will only take the word "of" and not strings with that substring.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to use a regexp :

```
page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")
```

`.*` means "any char zero or more times".
`\\b` is a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes).
`[Oo]` means the character 'O', upper case or lower case.

Here are some test cases:

```
String page = "Paint, Body & Trim : Body : Moldings : Sunroof";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // false
page = "A piece of cake";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // true
page = "What I'm made of";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // true
page = "What I'm made of.";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // true
page = "What I'm made of, flesh";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // true
page = "Of the Night";
System.out.println(page.matches(".*\\b[Oo][Ff]\\b.*")); // true
```

Matching " of " (with spaces before and after) will not work in the cases where "of" is at the beginning, at the end, before a punctuation,...

Answer (score 0):

or another way if you just look whole of word:

```
String page="Paint, Body & Trim : Body : Moldings : Sunroof";
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");//space

        while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
            if((st2.nextElement().equals("of")){
              //whatever..
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if (page.matches(".*\\bof\\b.*")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex here it would make it easy else you need to add many checks:

```
System.out.println(str.matches(".*\\bof\\b.*"));   //will return true
```

Here is [Demo](http://ideone.com/cuNOHW)

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces before and after the search string,
i.e

```
if(page.contains(" of ")){
}
```

Other way is splitting sentence with space delimeter, but here you need to loop throgh the string array.