# Powershell search for string in array with special characters

Tags: regex, powershell

Powershell question:
I have an array $myArray that contains the following values:

```
$myArray[0]:smith,server1,1/1/2015 10:00:00
$myArray[1]:smithpeter,server1,1/1/2015 10:00:00
```

I'd like to find out if $myArray already contains the value "smith" anywhere, but I do not want to include "smith*" (e.g. smithpeter) in the results.

If I try

```
[regex]$regex="smith"
$myArray -match $regex
```

it returns both records (smith and smithpeter) --> correct, but not what I want.

If I try

```
[regex]$regex="smith,"
$myArray -match $regex
```

I am getting no results.

I can't find any proper answers online. I believe the fact that I have a comma (",") in the string seems to be causing some issues with the query.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Try `[regex]$regex="\bsmith\b"`.

Answer (score 3):

All you  need is to add a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) round `smith` to match it as a whole word.

```
[regex]$regex="\bsmith\b"
```

Also see [What is a word boundary in regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes) SO post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to word-boundary, you can use the caret "^" to indicate the start position of the expression and the dollar sign "$" to indicate the end.

```
[regex]$regex="^smith$"
```