# Negating a pattern from a subset of another pattern using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, sas

I want to use the PRXCHANGE function in SAS to replace strings which have the pattern

```
[string ending in a lower case letter][string beginning in upper case letter]
```

but such that this pattern did not arise from a string such as "McCoy" or "MacDonald" (and possibly other exceptions which I can hard code), and replace the entire string with the second substring above. I can't quite figure out how to negate from only a subset of strings.

Comment: you can use a negative lookahead like `(?!MacDonald|McCoy)putyourregexhere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
/\b(?!Mc|Mac)\w*[a-z][A-Z]\w*\b/
```

Testing in Perl:

```
$ cat file
MacDonald
John_doe
BillyTheRock
McCoy
$ perl -ne 's/\b(?!Mc|Mac)\w*[a-z][A-Z]\w*\b/__replaced__/;print;' file
MacDonald
John_doe
__replaced__
McCoy
```

Breakdown:

```
/
  \b # word boundary
  (?!Mc|Mac) # negative lookahead for Mc or Mac
  \w* # a word zero or more times
  [a-z] # lower case
  [A-Z] # UPPER CASE
  \w* # a word zero or more times
  \b # word boundary
/
```

[What is a word boundary in regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)

Comment: Thanks, ended up going with something similar. Problem was that if you use a look behind instead of a look ahead SAS tells you that you are using a variable length expression and doesn't support that. +1