# Regex issue with dash

Tags: regex

I am having some issue with regular expression.
I am testing wit case 1

```
\b(water|watering)\b/g
```

the above expression can match "water watering" successfully.

But if I added a hyphen in between for case 2:

```
\b(water|water-ing)\b/g
```

It can't match the water-ing in "water water-ing". 
It only works if I move "water-ing" expression to the front, as in case 3:

```
\b(water-ing|water)\b/g
```

But I wish to find out if there is any solution for the case number 2, without modifying the sequence of capturing groups.

Here is the reference: https://regex101.com/r/kR1bL0/2

Comment: This is happening because of the `-` in `water-ing` and word boundary `\b`.

Comment: You cannot achieve what you want without either reordering or changing the first branch pattern. What I mean is: 1) [`/\b(water-ing|water)\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pM4mV7/1) or [`/\bwater(?:-ing)?\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pM4mV7/2), or 2)  [`/\b(water(?!-)|water-ing)\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pM4mV7/4).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
\b(water-ing|water)\b/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/fC8wO1/1

Because "water" is inside "water-ing" you have to put first "water-ing" and if the regex can't find it, the it try to find "water".

Or you can do this:

```
\b(water(?:-ing)?)\b/g
```

It is important to use "?:" to avoid create another group with the "()".

https://regex101.com/r/yC8uM2/3

Comment: The outer parentheses are not beneficial when avoiding alternation because that capture group is identical to the fullstring match.

Answer (score 2):

**Note About Alternation**

In alternation, every alternative is checked at current position in the string until one of the alternation succeeds or all of them fails.

**Case I**

Your string is

```
water watering
```

Your regex is

```
/\b(water|watering)\b/g
```

i) First of all, first alternation is checked like `\bwater`. It succeeds and `water` is matched because there is a space after water in `water watering` which serves as end word boundary.

ii) Due to `g` flag again a match is performed. So string `watering` is being tried to match with `\bwater\b`(along with word boundary in end) but it fails because there is `i` in watering after `water` which is not word boundary. Then second alternation is checked i.e. `\bwatering` and it succeeds because there is end of string which serves as word boundary for `\bwatering\b` in last.

**Case II**

Your string is

```
water water-ing
```

For regex

```
/\b(water|water-ing)\b/g
```

i) Same as Step I of Case I

Now string upto water is consumed and our checking position is blank space before watering

```
water water-ing
    ^^
    ||
```

ii) Again a checking is performed due to `g` flag. First alternation is tried with `\bwater`. The position now is `-` just after `r` and before `i`

```
water water-ing
          ^^
          ||
```

Quoting from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)** about word boundary

> A word boundary, in most regex dialects, is a position between \w and
>   \W (non-word char), or at the beginning or end of a string if it
>   begins or ends (respectively) with a word character ( [0-9A-Za-z_] ).
>   The dash is not a word character.

So `-` acts as a word boundary and `\bwater\b` is matched in `water-ing`

[image]

**Case III**

For regex

```
/\b(water-ing|water)\b/g
```

i) First alternation `\bwater-ing` is checked in the string but it does not matches the string `water`. Again, second alternation `\bwater` is checked and it succeeds because there is a space after `water` in the string.

ii) First alternation `\bwater-ing` is checked in the string which is present. The string ends with this word `water-ing`. So end of string(`$`) acts as word boundary. and match succeeds.

[image]
[image]

**What's the solution?**

i) If there is overlapping regex, keep the longest one in starting and so on as you used in your last solution

ii) You can use negative lookahead like

```
\b(water(?!-)|water-ing)\b
```

It seems [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) has already suggested four solutions. You can use any of them

Answer (score 0):

Different regular expression engines define different character sets for a "word boundary". For example, [ECMAScript specifies a word character as one of 63 characters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.6), and `-` is not listed there. So `-` is considered as a word boundary in ECMAScript.

Obviously, `\b` is not suitable for Unicode words. So you should use your own set of characters which are supposed to be word boundaries.

For example, in PHP you might use the following:

```php
preg_match_all('/[\p{L}\-]+/u', 'water water-ing', $m);
var_dump($m);
/*
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "water"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "water-ing"
  }
}
*/
```

where `\p{L}` stands for a [Unicode "letter" category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category). See [PHP Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:
`\b(water(ing)?)\g`

Comment: The outer parentheses are not beneficial because that capture group is identical to the fullstring match.