# Regular expression match on online tool does not match in Java when there is a special character at the end

Tags: java, regex

I have following regular expression

```
(?i)\b((https?:\/\/www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))?(localhost).*\b
```

and following url

http://localhost:8081/saman/ab/cde/fgh/ijkl.jsf?gdi=ff8081abcdef02a011b0af032170001&ci=

It matches when tried with both https://regex101.com/ and http://rubular.com/r/kyiKS9OlsM

But when there is any special character at the end, url does not match

```
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class JavaApplication1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static final String URL_MATCH_REGEX = "(?i)\\b((https?:\\/\\/www\\.)|(https?:\\/\\/)|(www\\.))?({0}).*\\b";
private static final Format format = new MessageFormat(URL_MATCH_REGEX);

static String regex = "";
static String url = "http://localhost:8081/saman/ab/cde/fgh/ijkl.jsf?gdi=ff8081abcdef02a011b0af032170001&ci=";
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        regex = format.format(new Object[]{replaceDomainToUseInRegex("localhost")});
        System.out.println(regex);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
                System.out.println(pattern.matcher( url ).matches());

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

private static String replaceDomainToUseInRegex(String domain) {
    return domain.replace(".", "\\.").replace("/", "\\/").replace("?", "\\?");
}

}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the issue here?

Comment: Regex101 checks PHP, Javascript and Python regex. Rubular is a *Ruby* regular expression editor.

Comment: Also your [rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/kyiKS9OlsM) doesn't use the regular expression you're using above.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes for a definition of "word boundary" in Java (i.e. `\\b`).

Comment: @JonnyHenly, corrected the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using two different kinds of matches.  Java's `matches()` requires the entire string to match the regular expression.  regex101.com does not.  So it says there's a match if *any substring* of your input string matches the regex.  However, in regex101.com, you can get the same kind of match by putting `^` in the front of the regex and `$` at the end; now it requires the entire string to match.  And it doesn't match.

(`\b` matches a "word boundary"; it matches the "zero-width substring" between a non-word character and a word character (in either order), or between a *word* character and the beginning or end of the string.  `=` is not a word character, thus `\b` doesn't match the position between `=` and the end of the string.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think in my case changing the regex as follows will work "(?i)\b((https?:\/\/www\.)|(https?:\/\/)|(www\.))?(localhost).*"