# Regex reused word boundary from first match in second match - why?

Tags: java, regex

Given string:

```
String str = "STACK 2013 OVERFLOW3";
```

And pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\s\\b");
```

The output is:

```
STACK 
2013
```

Why? I read that once a character is used in the match, it can't be used again in next match.

But here we have first match for `"\\b\\w+\\s\\b"`:

**\b** used for boundary (before word STACK)

**\w+** used for STACK word

**\s** used for space after STACK

**\b** used for boundary (before word 2013)

This results, as expected, in match "STACK ".

And then we have second match for "\b\w+\s\b":

**\b** used for boundary (before word 2013) <--- **HERE this boundary is used second time**

**\w+** used for 2013 word

**\s** used for space after 2013

**\b** used for boundary (before word OVERFLOW3)

Why word boundary before word "2013" is used twice in these matchings?

Full code to reproduce:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "STACK 2013 OVERFLOW3";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\s\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: A word boundary isn't a character, but a zero-width-assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are some good examples and descriptions of a word boundary in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes). Exact *positions* where a word boundary matches are outlined there, and in [this regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

However, your question is why does `\b` match at one and the same location twice?

The answer is that a word boundary belongs to the group of *non-consuming* patterns that do not add text they match to the output and they do not make the regex index advance to the end of the pattern matched, they just *assert* if there is something before or after the their patterns. In  other words, these are zero-width assertions (as already mentioned by [Sebastian Proske](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690538/regex-reused-word-boundary-from-first-match-in-second-match-why#comment66680416_39690538)).

Non-consuming patterns are lookarounds, anchors, and the word boundaries.

So, what happens when your regex reaches the end of `STACK` ? The trailing `\b` matches the *position* before `2013`, but the regex index is still there, before `2013`. The first match  is returned, the next match starts at the same position before `2013`. The first / leading `\b` in the pattern asserts true as the position before `2013` is a word boundary (after a non-word and before a word char).

The point that `\b` is a zero-width assertion can also be illustrated by using it inside a lookaround: the results are the same with both lookbehind and lookahead: `\b` = `(?<=\b)` = `(?!\b)`. They all give the same results.