# Regex to exclude alpha-numeric characters

Tags: regex

I thought `[^0-9a-zA-Z]*` excludes all alpha-numeric letters, but allows for special characters, spaces, etc.

With the search string `[^0-9a-zA-Z]*ELL[^0-9A-Z]*` I expect outputs such as

```
ELL 
ELLs 
The ELL 
Which ELLs
```

However I also get following outputs

```
Ellis Island
Bellis
```

How to correct this?

Comment: [Enclose the pattern with word boundaries](https://regex101.com/r/9lAaTj/1)? What are the requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Regex should capture 'ELL' and 'ELLs'

Comment: Why should it *capture* these substrings? Why not just match? What is expected output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's part of python program that read a filename and assigns a category based on keywords. `ELL`, `ELLs`, `_ELL-`, `ELLs--` etc will get assigned a category. Sometimes there are non-alphanumeric characers around ELL and ELLs, which Regex should take into account.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Still struggling working on this, i.e. it doesn't capture 'ELLs` or `_ELLs`

Comment: Try [`(?:\b|_)ELLs?(?=\b|_)`](https://regex101.com/r/9lAaTj/3). It will find `ELL` or `ELLs` if it is surrounded with `_` or non-word chars, or at the start/end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works! Thank you so much. If you put this in an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Ok..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\b|_)ELLs?(?=\b|_)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9lAaTj/3).

It will find `ELL` or `ELLs` if it is surrounded with `_` or non-word chars, or at the start/end of the string.

**Details**:

- `(?:\b|_)` - a non-capturing alternation group matching a word boundary position (`\b`) or (`|`) a `_`
- `ELLs?` - matches `ELL` or `ELLs` since `s?` matches 1 or 0 `s` chars
- `(?=\b|_)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of a word boundary or `_`  immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

change the * to +

a * means any amount including none.  A + means one or more.  What you probably want though is a word boundry:

```
\bELL\b
```

A word boundry is a position between \w and \W (non-word char), or at the beginning or end of a string if it begins or ends (respectively) with a word character ([0-9A-Za-z_]).  More here about that:
[What is a word boundary in regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)