# Negative lookahead not working after character range with plus quantifier

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to implement a regex which includes all the strings which have any number of words but cannot be followed by a : and ignore the match if it does. I decided to use a negative look ahead for it.

```
/([a-zA-Z]+)(?!:)/gm
string: lame:joker
```

since i am using a character range it is matching one character at a time and only ignoring the last character before the : .
How do i ignore the entire match in this case?

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/DlEmC9/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a word boundary check `\b` after the `+` to require it to get to the end of the word.

```
([a-zA-Z]+\b)(?!:)
```

[Here's an example run](http://regexr.com/3grho).

Answer (score 6):

The issue is related to **backtracking**: once your `[a-zA-Z]+` comes to a `:`, the engine steps back from the failing position, re-checks the lookahead match and finds a match whenver there are at least two letters before a colon, returning the one that is not immediately followed by `:`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DlEmC9/3): `c` in `c:real` is not matched as there is no position to backtrack to, and `rea` in `real:c` is matched because `a` is not immediately followed with `:`.

**Adding implicit requirement to the negative lookahead**

Since you only need to match a sequence of letters not followed with a colon, you can explicitly add one more condition that is implied: *and not followed with another letter*:

```php
[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z]|:)
[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z:])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLLV2y/2). Since both `[A-Za-z]` and `:` match a single character, it makes sense to put them into a single character class, so, `[A-Za-z]+(?![A-Za-z:])` is better.

**Preventing backtracking into a word-like pattern by using a word boundary**

As [@scnerd suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458459/3832970), word boundaries can also help in these situations, but there is always a catch: word boundary meaning is context dependent (see a number of *ifs* in the [word boundary explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324784/3832970)).

```
[A-Za-z]+\b(?!:)
```

is a valid solution here, because the input implies the words end with non-word chars (i.e. end of string, or chars other than letter, digits and underscore). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLLV2y/3).

*When does a word boundary fail?*

`\b` will not be the right choice when the main consuming pattern is supposed to match even if glued to other word chars. The most common example is matching numbers:

- `\d+\b(?!:)` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/antZu5/1) `12` in `12,`, but not in `12:`, *and also* `12c` and `12_`
- `\d+(?![\d:])` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/antZu5/2) `12` in `12,` *and* `12c` and `12_`, not in `12:` only.