# Regex match numbers not followed by a hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I've worked with regexes for years and never had this much trouble working out a regex. I am using PHP 7.2.2's `preg_match()` to return an array of matching numbers for parsing, hence the parentheses in the regex.

I am trying to match one or more numbers followed by an `x` followed by one or more numbers where the entire string is not followed by a hyphen. When $input is `18x18`, `18x18-` or `18x18size`, the matches are `18` and `1`. When the `$input` is `8x8`, there are no matches.

I seem to be doing something fundamentally wrong here.

```
<?php
$input = "18x18";    
preg_match("/(\d+)x(\d+)[^-]/", $input, $matches);
```

Calling the `print_r($matches)` results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18x18
    [1] => 18
    [2] => 1
)
```

The parens are there because I am using PHP's preg_match to return an array of matches. I understand when hyphens should be escaped and I've tried both ways to be sure but get the same results. Why doesn't this match?

Comment: Do you want it like [`'~(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/vvDqST/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you explain the possessive `++` please?

Comment: PCRE regex should not be confused with Python `re` that does not support possessive quantifiers, thus it cannot be closed as [Negative lookahead not working after character range with plus quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458408/negative-lookahead-not-working-after-character-range-with-plus-quantifier) duplicate.

Comment: This question is not about use of possessive quantifiers. It is about matching something not followed by a character. As shown in [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46458459/548225) how a word boundary solution is suffice for both `python` and `php`.

Comment: No, it is not always sufficient. Word boundary is not a solution at all, it is a *workaround*. `(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?!-)` [won't match](https://regex101.com/r/tgDrns/1) the size in `12x24size`, while `(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)` [will](https://regex101.com/r/tgDrns/2).

Comment: When the input - as per OP - can be both  `18x18` or `18x18-`, the `12x24size` is also necessary to handle.

Comment: `12x24size` is not part of OP's requirement. Requirement should come from OP not from the posted answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)~'
```

It can also be written without a possessive quantifier as [`'~(\d+)x(\d+)(?![-\d])~'`](https://regex101.com/r/vvDqST/3) since the `\d` inside the lookahead will also forbid matching the second digit chunk partially.

Alternatively, additionally to the lookahead, you may use word boundaries:

```
'~\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?!-)~'
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/vvDqST/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/vvDqST/2).

**Details**

- `(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)` / `(\d+)x(\d+)(?![-\d])` - matches and captures 1 or more digits into Group 1, then matches `x`, and then matches and captures into Group 2 one or more digits *possessively* without letting backtracking into the digit matching pattern, and the `(?!-)` negative lookahead check (making sure there is no `-` immediately after the current position) is performed *once* after `\d++` matches all the digits it can. In case of `\d+(?![-\d])`, the 1+ digits are matched first, and then the negative lookahead makes sure there is no digit *and* `-` immediately to the right of the current location.
- `\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?!-)` - matches a word boundary first, then matches and captures 1 or more digits into Group 1, then matches `x`, then matches and captures into Group 2 one or more digits, then asserts that there is a word boundary, and only then makes sure there is no `-` right after.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/x4OEi2):

```
if (preg_match('~(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)~', "18x18", $m)) {
    echo "18x18: " . $m[1] . " - " . $m[2] . "\n";
}
if (preg_match('~\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?!-)~', "18x18", $m)) {
    echo "18x18: " . $m[1] . " - " . $m[2] . "\n";
}
if (preg_match('~(\d+)x(\d++)(?!-)~', "18x18-", $m)) {
    echo "18x18-: " . $m[1] . " - " . $m[2] . "\n";
}
if (preg_match('~\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b(?!-)~', "18x18-", $m)) {
    echo "18x18-: " . $m[1] . " - " . $m[2];
}
```

Output:

```
18x18: 18 - 18
18x18: 18 - 18
```

Comment: In addition, see [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers) for more info about the possessive quantifier (I'm leaving this here since I was confused myself)

Comment: @Zenoo I added an equivalent pattern that does not use a possessive quantifier.

Comment: I am astounded at how complex this turns out to be but it works perfectly. Something so simple should be easier to accomplish. I have never used possessive quantifiers or word boundaries before. I will need to study to understand their use. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Wiktor may I ask what is the difference between `\d++` and `\d+` here? or in general.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR `\d++` is modified with a possessive quantifier, which forbids backtracking into the pattern (=no re-matching the input string is allowed, once the one or more digits is matched the first time, there regex index cannot go back through this matched text). So, in `\d++(?!x)` the negative lookahead is executed once after all digits are matched, and if there is no `x`, the whole match is failed, no match is returned. In case of `\d+(?!x)`, backtracking into `\d+` is allowed, and if there are two or more digits followed with `x`,the last one will be cut off and then match will occur.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation dear Wiktor.