# Display all files that begin with 3 digits

Tags: linux, grep, find, digits, kali-linux

I need to find all files in root directory that begin with 3 digits.

I am using the `find` command, and so far I've tried with

```bash
find . -type f -name '[[digit]]'*' | grep -E '.*/[100-999]+$'
```

but it shows me completely different result.

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to get the correct result?

Comment: What if the file name starts with four digits? `[100-999]` is equal to `[0-9]`, and your regex requires the file name to only contain one or more digits.

Comment: thank you, completely misinterpreted the usage of this one

Comment: `echo /[0-9][0-9][0-9]*` finds all files in `/` whose name begins with three digits. You absolutely don't need `find` for this.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `[100-999]` is equal to `[0-9]`, and your regex requires the file name to only contain one or more digits. Also, you missed the colons in the POSIX character class definition, `[[digit]]` must look like `[[:digit:]]` if you plan to match a digit in the glob `-name` pattern.

If you want to find files with name starting with 3 digits (and then there can be anything, including more digits) you can use

```sh
find . -type f -name '[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*'
find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]*'
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{3}[^/]*$'
```

Note:

- `find . -type f -name '[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*'` or `find . -type f -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9]*'` - here, the name "pattern" is a glob pattern that matches the entire file name and thus it must start with 3 digits and then `*` wildcard matches any text till the file name end
- `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{3}[^/]*$'` - if you prefer to play with regex, or extend in the future - it matches any text till last `/` and then 3 digits and any text other than `/` till the end of string.
  If there can be only three and not four digits at the start, you need

```sh
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[0-9]{3}([^0-9][^/]*)?$'
```

Here,

- `.*/` - matches up to the last `/` char including it
- `[0-9]{3}`  - any three digits
- `([^0-9][^/]*)?` - an optional occurrence of a non-digit and then zero or more chars other than a `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Curious about `[[:digit:]]`, is there a shell that doesn't support `[0-9]` ?

Comment: Also, you could simplify `[0-9]{3}([^0-9][^/]*)?$` to `[0-9]{3}[^0-9/]*$`

Comment: @Sundeep No, `[0-9]{3}[^0-9/]*$` won't match `123-good-name01.txt`

Comment: Oh, good point... possessive quantifier would have made that easier..

Comment: Good point again, I just tried what I thought would work, but didn't (lookaround helps though)..  I think `[^0-9]` should be `[^0-9/]` though, otherwise `./123/-good-name01.txt` will match

Comment: Just rephrasing the previous comment I deleted:  I doubt a possessive quantifier is necessary here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264400/) is a good use case for a possessive quantifier.