# Regex should fail if pattern is followed by another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I need to detect `@username` mentions within a message, but NOT if it is in the form of `@username[user_id]`. I have a regex that can match the `@username` part, but am struggling to negate the match if it is followed by `\[\d\]`.

```py
import re

username_regex = re.compile(r'@([\w.@-]+[\w])')

usernames = username_regex.findall("Hello @kevin") # correctly finds kevin
usernames = username_regex.findall("Hello @kevin.") # correctly finds kevin
usernames = username_regex.findall("Hello @kevin[1].") # shouldn't find kevin but does
```

The regex allows for usernames that contain `@`, `.` and `-`, but need to end with a `\w` character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). How can I extend the regex so that it fails if the username is followed by the userid in the `[1]` form?

I tried `@([\w.@-]+[\w])(?!\[\d+\])` but then it matches `kevi`

I'm using Python 3.10.

Comment: `.compile(r'@([\w.@-]*\w)\b(?!\[\d+\])')`, add a word boundary.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks! Can you explain why/how it works? If you put it in an answer I can accept it as well.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work correctly: `usernames = username_regex.findall("Hello @kev._in[1].")` finds `kev`, whereas it shouldn't find anything. It's because usernames can have more than just letters and numbers.

Comment: Kevin, I wanted to add that the problem could have been solved if Python `re` supported possessive quantifiers or atomic groups. Unfortunately, it is not so. All you would need then would be a pattern like `@[\w.@-]*+\w(?!\[\d+])`. See [an example and explanation of how possessive quantifiers work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51264400/3832970).

Comment: No problem, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "emulate" possessive matching with

```py
@(?=([\w.@-]*\w))\1(?!\[\d+\])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N431a6/1/).

*Details*:

- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?=([\w.@-]*\w))` - a positive lookahead that matches and captures into Group 1 zero or more word, `.`, `@` and `-` chars, as many as possible, and then a word char immediately to the right of the current position (the text is not consumed, the regex engine index stays at the same location)
- `\1` - the text matched and captured in Group 1 (this consumes the text captured with the lookahead pattern, mind that backreferences are atomic by nature)
- `(?!\[\d+\])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `[` + one or more digits + `]` immediately to the right of the current location.