# Python Regex: Find integer with possible zeros after comma

Tags: python, regex

I have the following case:

```
Test (2.00001) Test (2.000) Test 2.1 Test (2,0001) Test 2,000 Test 2,1000 test 2
```

I try to use regex to find only the integers:

1. `2.000`
2. `2,000`
3. `2`

but not the other float numbers.
I tried different things:

```
re.search('(?<![0-9.])2(?![.,]?[1-9])(?=[.,]*[0]*)(?![1-9]),...)
```

but this returns true for:

1. `2.00001`
2. `2.000`
3. `2,000`
4. `2,0001`
5. `2`

What have I to do?

**UPDATE**
I have updated the question and it should also find an integer without any comma and point, too (`2`).

Comment: Try `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?![,.]?\d)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does not match all integers in `test 2 2.00`

Comment: If you do NOT want to match `2.00001`, why do you want to match `2.00`? How can you formulate the pattern requirements regarding differentiation between valid and non-valid floats?

Comment: Mathematically the value of `2.00` is an integer, the value of `2.0001` is not. I am looking if the integer `2` is existing in the string.

Comment: What about `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])(?:\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*|\d{4,})(?:(?!\1)[.,]0+)?(?![,.]?\d)`? See https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/2

Comment: If you do not need to support thousand separators: `(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d+(?:[.,]0+)?(?![,.]?\d)` - see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
import re

text = 'Test (2.00001) Test (2.000) Test 2.1 Test (2,0001) Test 2,000 Test 2,1000'

re.findall(r'(\d+[.,]0+)(?!\d)', text)
```

Output:

```
['2.000', '2,000']
```

Regex:

```
(        # start capturing
\d+      # match digit(s)
[.,]     # match . or ,
0+       # match one or more zeros
)        # stop capturing
(?!\d)   # ensure the last zero is not followed by a digit
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cEFbzo/1)

If you also want to match "intergers" alone, surrounded by spaces or parentheses/brackets:

```
import re

text = 'Test (2.00001) Test (2.000) Test 2.1 Test (2,0001) Test 2,000 Test 2,1000 2'

re.findall(r'(?:^|[(\s[])(\d+(?:[.,]0+(?!\d))?)(?=[]\s)]|$)', text)
```

Regex:

```
(?:^|[(\s[])      # match the start of string or [ or ( or space
(                 # start capturing
\d+               # match digit(s)
(?:[.,]0+(?!\d))? # optionally match . or , with only zeros
)                 # stop capturing
(?=[]\s)]|$)      # match the end of string or ] or ) or space
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hNnHj/1)

Comment: Ok, I have to update my question. It should of course also match `2` alone without `,` and `.`.

Comment: @CodePope OK, but how do you define a number? can you have cases like `abc123` or `127.0.0.0`?

Comment: No, such cases are not possible. Numbers appear either in brackets or have at least whitespace prior to them.

Comment: But it does not match all integers when the string is `2  2.00 `.

Comment: You said there is "*at least whitespace prior to them*", I didn't include a start of string boundary, let me update ;)

Comment: Thanks. Could you add some descriptions like your first regular expression. It would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @CodePope have you seen the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1hNnHj/1) link? This provides a detailed explanation of all the steps. But I'll try to add something

Comment: It is not good  to use  a negative lookahead after a quantified pattern like `0+(?!\d)`. If there are `0001`, it will just match the first two zeros. It won't fail the match.

Comment: @Wiktor thanks for the feedback, how would you suggest to improve it? using the negative lookahead **before** the quantifier? `(?:0(?!\d))+`?

Comment: @Wiktor I certainly trust your regex expertise, but I don't understand how my approach would not work, on the example you provided as comment, my regex works and also uses less steps. I'd appreciate a lot a counter-example if you have one.

Comment: See your `re.findall(r'(\d+[.,]0+)(?!\d)', text)` solution and then see [*Negative lookahead not working after character range with plus quantifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760343/3832970). The second solution will need boundary adaptation each time a new boundary char appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\b(?<!\d[.,])\d+(?:[.,]0+)?\b(?![,.]\d)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/7). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d[.,])` - no digit followed with `.` or `,` immediately on the left
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]0+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then one or more zeros
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?![,.]\d)` - no `,` or `.` and a digit allowed immediately to the right.

If you need to support thousand separators:

```py
pattern = r'\b(?<!\d[.,])(?:\d{1,3}(?:(?=([.,]))(?:\1\d{3})+)?|\d{4,})(?:(?!\1)[.,]0+)?\b(?![,.]\d)'
matches = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/8).

Comment: There is one problem with that and I know I haven't given this sample, but if a have a string like `GB2L 114`, it will also return the 2 inside the string.

Comment: @CodePope Then you need a different type of boundaries: `(?<!\d[.,])\b\d+(?:[.,]0+)?\b(?![,.]\d)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qrG8hg/4).

Comment: This regex works. Could you also extend it to include the logic for thousand separators?

Comment: It seems to have a problem: It detects patterns like `2,102.120` i.e. a decimal with one zero at the end.

Comment: @CodePope I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Without the need for regex, you can also consider using `is_integer()` after trying to conver the values into their respective numeric formats. While a little bit harder to read, it removes the need for regex and should be robust for further use cases given the string structure you provide:

```
[x for x in string.split() if float((pd.to_numeric(x.replace(r'(','').replace(r')','').replace(r',','.'),errors='coerce'))).is_integer()]
```

Returning the former values in the list:

```
['(2.000)', '2,000', '2']
```

Or if you'd like them cleaned:

```
[x for x in string.replace(r'(','').replace(r')','').replace(r',','.').split() if float((pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'))).is_integer()]
```

Returning:

```
['2.000', '2.000', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy - just get a number and check "is this an int value?".
Meaby something like this...

```
import re

text = 'Test (2.00001) Test (2.000) Test 2.1 Test (2,0001) Test 2,000 Test 2,1000 test 2'
out_ints = []
for x in  re.findall(r'([0-9.,]+)', text):
    possible_int = x.replace(',', '.')
    is_int = int(float(possible_int)) == float(possible_int)
    if is_int:
        out_ints.append(int(float(possible_int)))

print(out_ints)
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 2]
```

Or am i missing something?