# Find and replace strings which are distinct words, but not substrings?

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a Python expression that would transform this chunk of text:

```
z= 10
zi = 300
print(z)
print(z * 180)
print(z - 3241)
y=z
print(type(z))
print(type(y))
print(type(z[0]))
print(type(z[1]))
```

into the following chunk of text:

```
K= 10
zi = 300
print(K)
print(K * 180)
print(K - 3241)
y=K
print(type(K))
print(type(y))
print(type(K[0]))
print(type(K[1]))
```

I have tried:

`newdata = filedata.replace("z", "K")`

But, this replaces all instances of `z`, whereas I would only like to replace words whose only letters are `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be achieved through the use of regular expression *word boundaries* (the `\b` seen before and after the target string `z` as the first argument to `re.sub`): [What is a word boundary in regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)

```
import re
newdata = re.sub(r"\bz\b", "K", filedata)
print(newdata)
```

The output of printing `newdata` will be:

```
K= 10
zi = 300
print(K)
print(K * 180)
print(K - 3241)
y=K
print(type(K))
print(type(y))
print(type(K[0]))
print(type(K[1]))
```

Comment: You beat me to it, but I used:  `r'\bz\b'` for my RE (imagine "buzz").   Possibly helpful t give the meaning of `\b`?

Comment: @cdarke Good point. I was targeting their specific input case, but surrounding the `z` with word boundaries would ensure this worked with any input.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a for loop but it is not working in a for loop but it works as a standalone text. I've tried the code below.  **new_val = r'\b{0}\b'.format(value)
    # newval = r"\b" + (value) + r"\b"**