# Why \S+ with boundaries does not extract non-space characters?

Tags: python, regex

```
print(re.search(r'\b\w+\b', '\t hell0_there(0,1) \tbbb'))     # Works fine - 'hell0_there'
print(re.search(r'\S+', '  hell0_there(0,1)\t bbb'))          # Works fine - 'hell0_there(0,1)'

print(re.search(r'\b\S+\b', '  hell0_there(0,1)  '))      # Missing paranthesis - 'hell0_there(0,1'
print(re.search(r'\b\S+\b','   1.3.6.1.4.1.9848.3.2.2.3(1,0)   ')) # Missing closed paranthesis

print(re.search(r'\b\S+\b', '\t hell0_there(0,1) \tbbb'))      # Same issue
print(re.search(r'\b\S+\b','\t  1.3.6.1.4.1.9148.3.2.2.3(1,0)  \tnnn')) # Same issue
```

---

Why non-space boundary(`'\b\S+\b'`) does not extract with closed paranthesis?

Comment: There is no word boundary between `)` and following space.

Comment: @PetSerAl `hell0_there(0,1)` is a single word. Isn't it?

Comment: `hell0_there(0,1)` is not a single word as word contains only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` characters. There is a word boundary between `1` and `)` but there no word boundary between `)` and space.

Comment: @overexchange No, it is not. You should reread definition of `\w`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I meant, `hell0_there(0,1)` are one or more non-space characters(`\S+`). Isn't it? Yes `\w` is short cut for  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Yes it is 1+ non-space characters but word boundary is always asserted between `\w` and `\W`. Looks like you just need to have `r'\S+'`

Comment: @anubhava Query edited

Comment: That query has already been answered I think. There is a word boundary between `1` and `)` but no word boundary between `)` and space (both `\W`).

Comment: Last two don't work fine either.

Comment: @revo you are right

Comment: @anubhava, could you write your comment as answer?

Comment: @anubhava what would be the regular expression to detect with `)` as well? as this is part of non-space character. `\S+`

Comment: @anubhava [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324784/3317808) says: *After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.* last word character is `e`. How come, `(` & `,` are within boundary?

Comment: @overexchange *How come, `(` & `,` are within boundary?* because them match `\S+` and there is a boundary between `0` and `)`.