# How to check for exact string of words

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I am trying to match a large set of words to a column of strings.  These words have to have an exact match.

I can do it for a single word at a time but for multiple words I having some issues.

```r
x = c("red", "redish", "green", "greenish")
grepl("red|green", ignore.case=TRUE, x)
```

I would like for this to return "red" and "green"; but not redish or greenish.

Answer (score 5):

Regex let's you use `\\b` for word boundaries:

```
grepl("\\bred\\b|\\bgreen\\b", x, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This will work well if you want to match the words within longer strings:

```
grepl("\\bred\\b|\\bgreen\\b",
      c("I want to match red", "But not Fred",
        "Green yes please", "ignore wintergreen"),
      ignore.case=TRUE)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

However, if you're doing whole string matching, regex is overkill, equality matching will be much faster:

```
tolower(x) %in% c("red", "green")
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

If we start with `patterns = c("red|green")` we can get to either of the needed cases above:

```
## use this with `%in%`
individual_words = unlist(strsplit(patterns, split = "\\|")) 

## or paste on the word boundaries for regex
word_boundary_patterns = paste0("\\b", individual_words, "\\b", collapse = "|")
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor, I am sorry I should have mentioned, that the list of words I have is very large.  Could we add \\b...\\b or ^...$ within the code.  I am having trouble adding those to the list of words separated by |, like "red|green".  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!! That helps.

Comment: There are some special cases that I have to deal with that has "-" and I need them to be read as a single word, that is, all words within a quote, like 'spring-concert' etc. In the example below I need a TRUE only for the last term -- x = c('5-year-old', '17-year-old', '7-year-old', 'year-old')
grepl("\\byear-old\\b", ignore.case=TRUE, x) .  Thanks for your help

Comment: Use the pattern `(?<!-)\\byear-old\\b` for that, where `(?<!-)` means "not preceded by a dash". You can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/903061) how word boundaries are defined. Special cases  like this one will have to be handled specially.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `^` and `$` to specify for the beginning and end of strings, respectively:

```
grepl("^red$|^green$", ignore.case = T, x)
```