# command.replaceAll("$player", player.getName()); | Bukkit

Tags: java

I'm working on a system there connect my website with my Minecraft Server through a JavaPlugin! But I had meet some problem when I try to replace `$player` in a String with my Minecraft Players Ing Name, please help :)

```java
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
if(results.next()) {
    String command = ""+results.getString(2);
    String newcmd = ""+command.replaceAll("\b$player\b", ""+player.getName());
    System.out.println(newcmd);
    player.sendMessage("\u00A75SpaceStore \u00A78\u00A7l| \u00A72Code Activated!");
}
```

String command is the same as "give $player stone"

Output

```
give $player stone
```

Comment: You have to escape the $ sign it is a special character in regex

Comment: Try `command.replaceAll("\b\\$player\b", ""+player.getName());`

Comment: so i should use another sign than that one instead?

Comment: I will try @KarthikeyanVaithilingam thx :)

Comment: Also the concatenation with empty string is not necessary.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam it still give me the same output

Comment: What is the input? Also is there any reason to have `\b`?

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry but I'm not sure on what you mean

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam My Variable "command" is "give $player stone" and that with ``\b`` was something i saw on a tutorial

Comment: ““+ can be removed.

Comment: Why you do not use String.format(..)?

Comment: Thx for your help guys i had solved it now, i should only change ``$`` to another sign like ``@`` and then it work, thx for your help and time. :)

Comment: You can also use `String::replace` instead of `String::replaceAll`. Former doesn't treat its first parameter like it's a regular expression, like the latter does.

Comment: As @Jens said you can use `String.format("give %s stone",player.getName())`

Comment: Mads - instead of just relying on tutorials, you should lookup the javadocs for the respective classes and methods and carefully read them.  Stuff in tutorials tends to be "dumbed down" ...  and glosses over important details that a programmer needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use double backslashes to specify the word boundary as stated in *Backslashes, escapes, and quoting* here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> It is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals that represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation by the Java bytecode compiler.

Second, there's no word boundary between the space and `$` symbol as they are both non-word symbols, you can read the explanation of the word boundary here: [What is a word boundary in regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)

The proper syntax will be 
    `System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\$player\\b", "user1"));`

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "give $player stone";
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\b\\$player\\b", "user1"));
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\$player\\b", "user1"));
}
```

It outputs:

```
give $player stone
give user1 stone
```