# Regex: removing multiple words from a string using "or" regex removes some words but not all

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
pattern = " LLC | CO | CORP | DIV "
col = pd.Series(' TEST LLC TEST CO TEST CORP TEST DIV ')
col = col.map(lambda x:re.sub(pattern, '  ', x))
col
```

which correctly gives:      TEST  TEST  TEST  TEST

However, when I replace the 2nd row with:

```
col = pd.Series(' COMPUTING DEVICES CO DIV CLDC ')
```

I get incorrect output:      COMPUTING DEVICES  DIV CLDC

So in the first example, DIV was correctly removed. However in the second example DIV was not removed even though the code is identical?

Any idea why? and how to fix it? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in your pattern you are matching certain keywords *along* with the whitespace (spaces) surrounding it. Therefore, in your second example, first the standalone `" CO "` gets matched. But by this point, your pattern has also [*consumed* the space after the `"CO"`](https://regex101.com/r/w31erx/2). Now the remaining string to be matched is `DIV ""CLDC"""`. Your pattern only accepts the keywords if they have surrounding whitespace, but your `DIV` in this case doesn't have a space before it.

```
 COMPUTING DEVICES CO DIV CLDC 
 |___________________|  # already consumed
                      |______|  # remaining string
```

A better way to accomplish what you want, is to match on [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes) using the `\b` specifier (this is so that you don't pick up the `CO` in `COMPUTING`

Here is the modified regex with [an online example](https://regex101.com/r/w31erx/1):

```
\b(LLC|CO|CORP|DIV)\b
```

This will match your keywords if they are standalone words and they will match without the whitespace. You can then replace these matches with an *empty string* `''` instead of `'  '`

Comment: Got it! great explanation, thanks. However I tried your method and it's not removing anything. Here's the code ```pattern = '\b(LLC|CO|CORP|DIV)\b'
col = pd.Series(' COMPUTING DEVICES CO DIV LLC CLDC ')
col = col.map(lambda x:re.sub(pattern, '  ', x))
col``` The result I'm getting is: 0     COMPUTING DEVICES CO DIV LLC CLDC

Comment: You need to escape the backslash or use a raw string: `pattern = r'\b(LLC|CO|CORP|DIV)\b'`. Note the `r''` for specifying a raw string

Comment: Yup that worked! However, the minor problem is that now I'm getting the unwanted double spaces that were left when the 'CO' for example was removed...can the regex take those out? or do I need a loop to replace double spaces?

Comment: I cannot see the spaces in your comment. Please surround your string with `\`\`` backticks

Comment: ``0     COMPUTING DEVICES    CLDC `` I did but still stack is removing the extra spaces...there are like 6 spaces between DEVICES and CLDC because 3 words were removed and for each there was space before and after

Comment: Looks fine? The space at the end was also there in the original string. You can use `strip()` to trip whitespaces from the ends

Comment: The 6 spaces are in between DEVICE and CLDC so strip() can't fix it. I can fix it with a loop but that's not very elegant...thanks a lot for your help anyway :-)

Comment: You can modify the regex to optionally include 0 or more spaces before or after the pattern by using `\s*`. I'm sure there's some variation that will fit your need

Comment: ```col = col.map(lambda x: re.sub(' +',' ', x)) ```  removes any 2 or more spaces

Comment: your solution used ```pattern = r'\b(LLC|CO|CORP|DIV)\b'``` however what happens if the pattern is not explicitly mentioned? i.e.let's say that ```pattern``` is actually being composed out of a csv file and accordingly the 'r' (raw text) command will not work in this case. Any suggestions how can I make it work in that case? Thanks! :-)