# How to make a regular expression match based on a condition?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a conditional regex, I know that there are other posts on stack overflow but there too specific to the problem.

---

## The Question

How can I create a regular expression that only looks to match something given a certain condition?

---

## An example

An example of this would be if we had a list of a string(**this is in java**):

```java
String nums = "42 36 23827";
```

and we only want to match if there are the same amount of `x`'s at the end of the string as there are at the beginning

> #### What we want in this example
>
> In this example, we would want a regex that checks if there are the same amount of regex's at the end as there are in the beginning. **The conditional part**: If there are `x`'s at the beginning, then check if there are that many at the end, if there are then it is a match.
>
> ---

## Another example

An example of this would be if we had a list of numbers (**this is in java**) in string format:

```java
String nums = "42 36 23827";
```

and we want to separate each number into a list

```java
String splitSpace = "Regex goes here";
Pattern splitSpaceRegex = Pattern.compile(splitSpace);
Matcher splitSpaceMatcher = splitSpaceRegex.matcher(text);
ArrayList<String> splitEquation = new ArrayList<String>();

while (splitSpaceMatcher.find()) {
    if (splitSpaceMatcher.group().length() != 0) {
        System.out.println(splitSpaceMatcher.group().trim());
        splitEquation.add(splitSpaceMatcher.group().trim());
    }
}
```

How can I make this into an array that looks like this:

```java
["42", "36", "23827"]
```

You could try making a simple regex like this:

```java
String splitSpace = "\\d+\\s+";
```

But that exludes the `"23827" because there is no space after it.
and we only want to match if there are the same amount of`x`'s at the end of the string as there are at the beginning

> #### What we want in this example
>
> In this example, we would want a regex that checks if it is the end of the string; if it is then we don't need the space, otherwise, we do. As @YCF_L  mentioned we could just make a regex that is `\\b\\d\\b` but I am aiming for something conditional.
>
> ---

## Conclusion

So, as a result, the question is, how do we make conditional regular expressions? Thanks for reading and cheers!

Comment: [try using `"\d+"`](https://regex101.com/r/QvFWMv/1/).

Comment: @Turing85 I don't agree with that [check](https://regex101.com/r/bxrMmO/1), instead I would go with [`\b\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/g92dpB/1)

Comment: @YCF_L thanks, will incorporate this in my answer.

Comment: Ok, if you want to use condition in your case, you can use `"\\d+\\s+|\\d+$"`, where `|` mean or

Comment: @YCF_L If you add that to your answer it will be a very good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no conditionals in Java regexes.

> I want a regex that checks if there are the same amount of regex's at the end as there are in the beginning. The conditional part: If there are x's at the beginning, then check if there are that many at the end, if there are then it is a match.

This may or may not be solvable.  If you want to know if a specific string (or pattern) repeats, that can be done using a back reference; e.g.

```
   ^(\d+).+\1$
```

will match a line consisting of an arbitrary number digits, any number of characters, and the same digits matched at the start.  The back reference `\1` matches the string matched by group `1`.

However if you want the same *number* of digits at the end as at the start (and that number isn't a constant) then you cannot implement this using a single (Java) regex.

Note that some regex languages / engines do support conditionals; see the Wikipedia [Comparison of regular-expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines#Language_features) page.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, it is nice to know that it isn’t possible to do in Java. Thanks a lot for your answer, I’m sure it will help all that view this question.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to use split which accept regex like so :

```
String[] split = nums.split("\\s+"); // ["42", "36", "23827"]
```

---

If you want to use Pattern with Matcher, then you can use String `\b\d+\b` with word boundaries.

```
String regex = "\\b\\d+\\b";
```

By using word boundaries, you will avoid cases where the number is part of the word, for example `"123 a4 5678 9b"` you will get just `["123", "4578"]`

Comment: You might want to leave one more sentance on what boundaries are.

Comment: @BeastCoder check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes and https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html for word boundary

Comment: I have added one more example. Thanks for your super-useful response

Comment: @BeastCoder I don't know what you don't understand in my question, check this demo here https://ideone.com/QYVl65, it gives you the same output you expect

Comment: No, I understand it all I just added one more example because Turing said that I needed to demonstrate a more conditional example, and also I don’t know who downvoted, I’ll upvote it though.

Comment: Thank you @Turing85 I think my answer is short, and your answer is complete version, even this I don't know why people dv without any reason

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the "conditional" in the question. The problem is solvable with a straight forward regular expression: `\b\d+\b`.

[<kbd>regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/QvFWMv/2/)

A fully fledged Java example would look something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String sample = "123 45 678 90";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
        final ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            results.add(matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println(results);
    }
}
```

Output: `[123, 45, 678, 90]`

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Pj2S4E)

Comment: Do you think I should change the example? I mean I want to figure out conditionals. Your answer is however helpful, but maybe you could include a solution that checks if it is the end of the String and also include this answer.

Comment: I do not fully get your point. For end of String, use `$`. For start of String, use `^`. Please try and construct an example with a "conditional".

Comment: I will change the example, but what I mean is doing something like: Check if it is at the end if a space is not needed at the end, otherwise if it is not the end we do need a space.

Comment: No! Please do not change the question. This would invalidate the answers. There are optional groups, e. g. [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ESgxR1/3/) only allows `@` as last character of a `String`.

Comment: I am going to add another example

Comment: Please, before you keep editing the question, try to come up with an example that represents your use case. And then open a new post.

Comment: Would you say that this is okay now? Your answer is still correct, there is just one more example

Comment: Yes, but it is still nothing "conditional". I would suggest reading a tutorial on regular expressions, e.g. [this one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Regex'es work a little bit different than "ordinary programming". Maybe the question will resolve itself through this.

Comment: @YCF-L aright thanks I might change the title of my question later, thank you.