# Python regular expression Understanding Boundary "\b"

Tags: python, regex

input :

```
- "example (.com)"
```

output :

```
- "example"
```

What I tried

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'\b\([\W\w]+\)\b')
#pattern=re.compile(r'\([\W\w]+\)')
print(pattern.sub("","example (.com)"))
```

This doesn't work but if I remove `\b` it works fine - why?

Comment: There's no word boundary there.

Comment: This is confusing I thought the Opening braces is the boundary start and closing braces is the boundary end , why is it that you say there are no word boundary ?

Comment: There is no [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) between a space and `(` Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself clear what the `\b` stands for:

```
(?:(?=\w)(?<!\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))
```

That is, either a word character ahead and not behind or the other way round. A word character (`\w`) stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and does not include `(` or `)`, so there's no word boundary between a space and a parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

`(` is not a word boundary, so `\b` won't match it.  Instead you could use `\B` to match the blank

Comment: `\B` does not match blanks, and even if it did, that would be the wrong thing to do here. `\B` matches any position that is not a word boundary.

Comment: oops, sorry I was wrong to write that \B matches the blank, but I do see it working in this case, why do you suggest it's wrong in this instance?