# regex issue with negate

Tags: r, regex

I want to pick up the pattern `mn` followed by two numbers.

My text is :

```
apple 20127041 needs the following changes from ab34 to mn35-f01 priority - mn43 mn56.
```

The expected output is `mn43` and `mn56`. It should not pick up `mn35-`

I am not able to negate the `-`.

```
dd <- c("apple 20127041 needs the following changes from ab34 to mn35-f01 priority - mn43 mn56 ")
str_extract_all(dd,'\\bmn[0-9]{2}\\b')
```

It is picking up - value as well.

Comment: Relevant discussion about what exactly a word boundary is in regex  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex

Answer (score 2):

Add a non consuming negative look ahead of `(?!-)`:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(dd,'\\bmn[0-9]{2}\\b(?!-)')
#[1] "mn43" "mn56"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_extract_all(dd,'mn[0-9]{2}[^-]')
[[1]]
[1] "mn43 " "mn56 "
```

Exclude the `-` from those characters allowed to appear behind the numbers. To get rid of the white space, use `trimws`and `unlist`:

```
trimws(unlist(str_extract_all(dd,'mn[0-9]{2}[^-]')))
[1] "mn43" "mn56"
```