# Replace strings with both regular and special characters with whitespace in between

Tags: regex, ruby, special-characters, whitespace, gsub

I'm looking for how to handle strings with both regular and special characters with whitespace in between.

text = `'You got a Check +'`

lookup_term = `check +`

replace_with_term = `'check+'`

Final product I'm looking for is `you got a check+`

I am currently using `text.downcase.gsub(/\blookup_term\b/, replace_with_term)` to handle lookup_term with regular characters, but I can't seem to fingure out how to handle the combo of regular expression + whitespace + special character.

Comment: Are you trying to remove spaces before or after symbols, or both before and after?

Comment: Try `text.downcase.gsub(/\blookup_term(?= \+)/, replace_with_term)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
text.downcase.gsub(/(?<!\w)#{Regexp.escape(lookup_term)}(?!\w)/, replace_with_term)
```

If you do not really want to get the string turned into lowercase, but just want case insensitive matching, use the `/i` modifier and remove `.downcase`:

```
text.gsub(/(?<!\w)#{Regexp.escape(lookup_term)}(?!\w)/i, replace_with_term)
```

See the [Ruby demo online](https://rextester.com/WABBA14982).

The resulting regex will look like `/(?<!\w)check\ \+(?!\w)/`, see [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/mxlsCxykfklgHf).

Note that `\b` meaning is context-dependent, [and matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324784/3832970) an empty space (a location)

1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

The `(?<!\w)check\ \+(?!\w)` pattern contains ***unambiguous word boundaries***, they always match the same way:

- `(?<!\w)` - a left-hand word boundary, requires a start of string position or any non-word character immediately to the left of the current location
- `check\ \+` - `check`, space and `+`
- `(?!\w)` - a right-hand word boundary, requires an end of string position or any non-word character immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thank you! This does solve the issue and `text.downcase.gsub(/(?<!\w)#{Regexp.escape(lookup_term)}(?!\w)/, replace_with_term)` returns `you got a check+` like I expected. (note: I do want it all lowercase, so using `.downcase` worked for me)