# How can i remove strings from sentences if string matches with strings in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, nlp

I have a `pandas.Series` with sentences like this:

```
0    mi sobrino carlos bajó conmigo el lunes       
1    juan antonio es un tio guay                   
2    voy al cine con ramón                         
3    pepe el panadero siempre se porta bien conmigo
4    martha me hace feliz todos los días
```

on the other hand, I have a list of names and surnames like this:

`l = ['juan', 'antonio', 'esther', 'josefa', 'mariano', 'cristina', 'carlos']`

I want to match sentences from the series to the names in the list. The real data is much much bigger than this examples, so I thought that element-wise comparison between the series and the list was not going to be efficient, so I created a big string containing all the strings in the name list like this:

`'|'.join(l)`

I tried to create a boolean mask that later allows me to index the sentences that contains the names in the name list by true or false value like this:

```
series.apply(lambda x: x in '|'.join(l))
```

but it returns:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
```

which is clearly not ok.

I also tried using `str.contains()` but it doesn't behave as I expect, because this method will look if any substring in the series is present in the name list, and this is not what I need (i.e. I need an exact match).

Could you please point me in the right direction here?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: i dont know what panda is but you could use regex even tho it might be heavier

Comment: surely yes but i don't master regex, but if you provide a functional regex, i could give it a try :)

Comment: @everyone Thanks to all of you guys!! I'm overwhelmed by all the support you provided. Thanks for your collaboration :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need exact match you can use word boundaries:

```
series.str.contains('|'.join(rf"\b{x}\b" for x in l))
```

For remove values by list is use generator comprehension with filtering only non matched values by splitted text:

```
series = series.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y for y in x.split() if y not in l))
print (series)
                            
0                mi sobrino bajó conmigo el lunes
1                                  es un tio guay
2                           voy al cine con ramón
3  pepe el panadero siempre se porta bien conmigo
4             martha me hace feliz todos los días
```

Comment: What does `rf` mean here?

Comment: @bigbounty - regex and f-string ;)

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know we could combine both. +1

Comment: Thank you again Jezrael. Could you just provide a bit more of information about what your code does please?

Comment: @Miguel2488 - Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @Miguel2488 - For first what is word boundary check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex).

Comment: @Miguel2488 - For second - you can split values by whitespaces by `.split()` - default splitter is whitespace. Then is used comprehension for iterate each splitted value and tested if no membership with list by `not in`, so removed matched values from list. Last is used `join` for add space for values of filtered list.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data = ["mi sobrino carlos bajó conmigo el lunes", "juan antonio es un tio guay", "martha me hace feliz todos los días"]

regexs = ['juan', 'antonio', 'esther', 'josefa', 'mariano', 'cristina', 'carlos']

for regex in regexs:

    for sentence in data:

        if re.match(regex, sentence):

            print True
        
        else:

            print False
```

I guess something simple like that could work

cf : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html

Comment: And be careful with the encoding for spanish is UTF-8 i think

Comment: for a full match just go for "^.*juan.*$"

Answer (score 1):

Regex to check if a word at the start or at the end or in between

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'texts': [
                             'mi sobrino carlos bajó conmigo el lunes',
                             'juan antonio es un tio guay',
                             'voy al cine con ramón',
                             'pepe el panadero siempre se porta bien conmigo',
                             'martha me hace feliz todos los días '
                             ]})

names = ['juan', 'antonio', 'esther', 'josefa', 'mariano', 'cristina', 'carlos']

pattern = "|".join([f"^{s}|{s}$|\\b{s}\\b" for s in names])

df[df.apply(lambda x: 
            x.astype(str).str.contains(pattern, flags=re.I)).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

one option is set intersection:

```
l = set(['juan', 'antonio', 'esther', 'josefa', 'mariano', 'cristina', 'carlos'])
s.apply(lambda x: len(set(x.split()).intersection(l))>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For exact match. Try;

```
df.text.str.contains("|".join(l))
```

Otherwise, simply use [regular expression](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to replace substring with `''`. Call the `substring` using list comprehension

```
df.replace(regex=[x for x in l], value='')
                          

                                   text
0               mi sobrino  bajó conmigo el lunes
1                                  es un tio guay
2                           voy al cine con ramón
3  pepe el panadero siempre se porta bien conmigo
4             martha me hace feliz todos los días
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a little more flexibility for processing, you can have your custom `exact_match` function as below:

```
import re 

def exact_match(text, l=l):
    return bool(re.search('|'.join(rf'\b{x}\b' for x in l), text))

series.apply(exact_match)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```