# Find special character like @ and wrap it to html tag with span or div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want find special character like @ from the string and wrap it to html tag like span or div, like
`var str = "@user you email id is some@gmail.com"`.

So i want @user to be `<span class="class">@user</span>`, but the email should not be effected as it also have `@`,

I am new to regex, but came up with an regex but it doesn't work `/\@[\w]+/g` but this also selects the @gmail from the email, which is incorrect, Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\B` to make sure there isn't a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex) right in front of `@`.

```
const str = "@user you email @id is some@gmail.com";
str.replace(/\B(\@\w+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

Result:

```
"<span>@user</span> you email <span>@id</span> is some@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
str = `<span>@user</span> you email id is some@gmail.com`
```

No need regex here.

Edit : With regex to get `@user` try [this](http://regexr.com/5d01l) `\B@\w+`

Comment: i want it from the string and the string is dynamic , please read the question properly

Comment: I would suggest bro to add atleast default string after the first `@` so it would be easier for you to identify the first `@` without affecting the emailaddress.