# How do I capitalize all occurrences of the word 'I' in a string? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I am trying to capitalize all occurrences of the word 'I' - not letter 'i'.

Input: `this is my input, how do i do capitalize the word i?`

Expected: `this is my input, how do I do capitalize the word I?`

I have tried a simple `.replace('i', 'I')` but obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression, and match `i` with word boundaries `\b` on both sides.

```
import re

output_string = re.sub(r'\bi\b', 'I', input_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex with word bounds surrounding "i" to replace it:

```py
import re

re.sub(r"\bi\b", "I", "this is my input, how do i do capitalize the word i?")
# outputs "this is my input, how do I do capitalize the word I?"
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/5923139) for more info on what a word bound is.