# How to find certain words using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am learning the ropes with regular expression in Python. I have the code below:

```
import re

test = '"(Z101+Z102+Z1034+Z104)/4"'
regex = re.compile(r"[\(\+]([XYZ]\d\d\d)[\)\+]")
regex.findall(test)
```

It returns:

```
['Z101', 'Z104']
```

However, when I change 'Z101' to 'YZ101':

```
import re

test = '"(YZ101+Z102+Z1034+Z104)/4"'
regex = re.compile(r"[\(\+]([XYZ]\d\d\d)[\)\+]")
regex.findall(test)
```

It returns:

```
['Z102', 'Z104']
```

The purpose is to extract strings containing `X`, `Y` or `Z` following by any set of three digits. Therefore, the desired output for the first code would be:

```
['Z101', 'Z102', 'Z104']
```

How to fix the compile and get the correct output?

Comment: The problem is very common: the left and right hand boundaries are consuming the text, and consecutive matches are not thus detected. Use lookarounds, `r"(?<=[(+])([XYZ]\d\d\d)(?=[)+])"`

Comment: Thank you, @WiktorStribiżew. The second comment is the exact solution and explanation which I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left and right hand boundary patterns (`[\(\+]` and `[\)\+]`) are consuming the text they match, and thus consecutive matches are not thus detected.

You can solve the problem [using **lookarounds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),

```py
r"(?<=[(+])([XYZ]\d\d\d)(?=[)+])"
r"(?<=[(+])[XYZ]\d{3}(?=[)+])"
```

*Details*

- `(?<=[(+])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is
  immediately preceded with `(` or `+`
- `[XYZ]` - `X`, `Y` or `Z`
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `(?=[)+])` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is `)` or `+` immediately to the right of the current location.

Note the [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex-does-b-match-hyphen), `\b`, can solve the issue in some situations, it might also help you here, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` with the pattern `[XYZ]\d{3}\b`:

```
test = '"(YZ101+Z102+Z1034+Z104)/4"'
matches = re.findall(r'[XYZ]\d{3}\b', test)
print(matches)  # ['Z101', 'Z102', 'Z104']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is looking for:

1. Either '(' or '+'
2. Exactly one of 'X', 'Y', or 'Z'
3. Exactly three numeric characters
4. Either '(' or '+'

It's not selecting the 'Z101' because when you add 'Y', that substring isn't immediately preceded by '(' or '+'.

One option would be to leave 1 and 4 out of the pattern. In this example, you would get exactly what you want. That pattern would be r'[XYZ]\d\d\d'. Depending on your data, however, that might create a different problem down the road.

Another option would be to include the possibility for a prefixed character with '?'. The '?' means 'zero or one' when used as a quantifier (but it can also modify other quantifiers, but that's a different topic). To do that, your pattern would be r"[(+][XYZ]?([XYZ]\d\d\d)[)+]"

Comment: I added 'Y' to not selecting 'Z101' on purpose. However, It returns 'Z102' while the first code did not which I am confused. I tried the pattern r"[(+][XYZ]?([XYZ]\d\d\d)[)+]" and it yields the same result as above - still missing 'Z102'.