# How can I match the string with boundary pattern if string starts with a dot symbol in PHP?

Tags: php

I am checking for some spam keywords using PHP preg_match().

The following code doesn't work if dot (.) is included in the `$keywords` and `$str`:

```
<?php
$keywords = array('.co.uk');
$errors = array();
$str = ".co.uk";

foreach($keywords as $keyword)
{
    if(preg_match("/\b($keyword)\b/i", $str))
    {
        $errors[] = "This is spam remove " . $keyword;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($errors);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

How can I add dot in the pattern `/\b($keyword)\b/i`?

Comment: You may have problems with `\b` as it may not take the . as being part of the same word - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex-does-b-match-hyphen

Comment: A `.` is a special char in regex. You need to escape those, maybe use `preg_quote`.

Comment: Yes problem arose because of `\b` but I do need this along with `.` How can I get it working?

Comment: Maybe something like https://3v4l.org/HWDHX