# regex to match a column separated string unlesss it starts with a hyphen

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex which matches a key value pair unless it has a hyphen in the beginning. This regex will detect the attribute set from a yaml file. Here is a sample yaml file content

```
containers:
  - name: api-php-container
    image: us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abcd:45
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
      - containerPort: 443
    volumeMounts:
        mountPath: "/etc/keys/ssl"
      - name: certs
```

The regex should match all lines which are like key:value pairs unless it has an hyphen in the beginning. For example, it will match the following lines:

```
image: us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abcd:45
mountPath: "/etc/keys/ssl"
```

Here is the regex I wrote:

```
^(\s*\-\s*)([\w0-9_\-\.]+)\s*:\s*([\w0-9_\-\.\/]+)\s*$
```

But this detects the lines which starts with the hyphen.

Then I tried using negative lookahead, but then it stopped matching the whole thing altogether. Here that regex:

```
^(?!(\s*\-\s))([\w0-9_\-\.]+)\s*:\s*([\w0-9_\-\.\/]+)\s*$
```

How do I make it detect like I want it?

Comment: Just curious. Why do you not want the lines starting with hyphen? If it has a colon then it is a key as important as any others whether it is preceded by a hyphen or not.

Comment: @blhsing I want to be able to differentiate between the key value pairs and the key value pairs which starts with hyphen.

Comment: You did not appear to have made any attempt to exclude a hyphen in your regex. Instead, you explicitly match a hyphen in your regex.

Comment: @blhsing I tried using `^(?!(\s*\-\s))([\w0-9_\-\.]+)\s*:\s*([\w0-9_\-\.\/]+)\s*$` but that didn't match anything.

Comment: There really is no such thing as a key value pair that starts with a hyphen. That hyphen simply means a list in YAML. It has nothing to do with the key value pairs themselves.

Comment: I didn't know what it was called. Thanks.

Comment: OK that regex looks like a more serious attempt in implementing the desired behavior. I would recommend that you update your question with that regex instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt with the negative lookahead is fairly close, but since your regex starts with an anchor of `^` it must match all the characters from the beginning of a line, including whitespaces, which means that you should place a `\s*` after your negative lookahead assertion. I would use a simple white space instead of `\s` here though, since `\s` also matches newline characters and may match a key-value pair over multiple lines. Use `[^:]+` to match a key and `\S.*?` to match a value to be more generic:

```
^(?! *-) *([^:]+) *: *(\S.*?) *$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GXDGX3/1

Answer (score 2):

You might also make sure that the first character you match is not a `-` `:` or a whitespace char:

```
^ *([^\s:-][^\s:]*) *: *(.+)$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `*` Optional spaces
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\s:-]` Match a single char other than a whitspace char `:` or `-`
  - `[^\s:]*` Match optional chars other than a whitespace char or `:`
- `)` Close group 1
- `*: *` Match `:` between optional spaces
- `(.+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ times any character
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dITbjk/1)

Answer (score 1):

#### This should work

```
(?<!-\s)\b.+:.+
```

#### Explanation

`(?<!-\s)`: negative lookbehind `(?<!...)` which finds strings which are not preceded by `...`, in this case by "-" and a whitespace character `\s`

`\b`: word boundary to make sure that what follows is the beginning of a "word" or: between a whitespace and a character (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/8131140) answer)

`.+:.+`: match at least one (`+`) character that is not a newline (`.`), followed by ":" and then, again, match at least one (`+`) character (`.`)