# Perl: Regex for matching and replacing word and optional full stop

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to capitalise some file names and also apply some exceptions to it. I have a series of substitutions, of which one is

```
s/\b(vs|etc)[.]?\b/\L$1./gir
```

With this I want to match any occurrence of "vs" or "Vs" or "vs." or "VS." or "etc." or "Etc" and so on. If the source string already has a full stop (eg. "Vs.") then I don't want to add one, otherwise I do want to add one. The resulting part of the string also needs to be lowercased, so that the only valid outputs are `vs.` or `etc.`.

It's probably just a trivial change, but I just can't find it. Can someone let me in on the thought process to assemble the regex, please?

Comment: You need to move the word boundary before optional `.`, `s/\b(vs|etc)\b\.?/\L$1./gir`

Comment: Thanks. That was one of the attempts I made, but it didn't make a difference in the result. Are you saying that a ```.``` is not counted towards a word?

Comment: Right, `\.\b` will only match if there is a letter, digit or `_` right after `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a [word boundary meaning is context-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324784/3832970).

Here, you need to move the word boundary before optional `.` as `\.\b` (i.e. when there is a `.` after, say, `etc`) will only match if there is a letter, digit or `_` right after `.`.

So, you can use

```perl
s/\b(vs|etc)\b\.?/\L$1./gir
```

See the [Perl demo online](https://ideone.com/HtkiM5):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "vs or Vs or vs. or VS. or etc avs and metch";
say $str =~ s/\b(vs|etc)\b\.?/\L$1./gir;
# => vs. or vs. or vs. or vs. or etc. avs and metch
```