# Grep for line having only 2 or 3 digits

Tags: grep

I'm trying to print line containing 2 or 3 numbers along with the rest of the line. I came with the code:

```
grep -P '[[:digit:]]{2,3}' address
```

But this even prints the line having 4 digits. I don know why is this happening.

Output:
[image]
Neither this code works;

```
grep -E '[0-9]{2,3}' address
```

[image]

Here is the file containing address text:

12 main st

123 main street

1234 main street

I have already specified to print 2 or 3 values with {2,3} still the filter doesn't work and more than 3 digits line is being printed. Can anyone assist me on this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try this: `^[[:digit:]]{2,3}\b` (this works if line start with number)

Comment: It does work that way. What does '\b' mean here?

Comment: It's word boundary, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex-does-b-match-hyphen) for more about the word boundary.

Comment: Another solution if after numbers always is a space: `^[[:digit:]]{2,3} `

Comment: By way of explanation, lines that contain 4-digit sequences, by definition, necessarily contain 3-digit sequences, so `grep` will find them too. You need to search for *"not a digit followed by 2 or 3 digits followed by not a digit"*.

Comment: Do not convert text into pixels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inverted grep (-v) to filter all lines with 4 digits (and above):

```
grep -vE '[0-9]{4}' address
```

EDIT:

I noticed you want only 2 or 3 digit along the line, so first command will get you also 1 digit.

Here's the fix, again using same method:

```
grep -E '[0-9]{2,3}' txt.txt | grep -vE '[0-9]{4}'
```