# How to match and extract string matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

This is main string:

> `MR HI Government He PIHe9 Hanumana Ji 3-� fafer/ DOB : 01/01/1959 989 / Male 2094 7051 9541 ������ - ��� ����� �� 3�1���`

I want to match and extract `2094 7051 9541` using regular expression

and regex pattern to find is:

```
^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{-3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$
```

I want to use javascript to match and extract string. But not able to find right syntax to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
PD

Comment: That should be: `/\s[2-9]\d{3}(?:\s\d{4}){2}\s/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a word boundary in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const regex = /\b[2-9]\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}\b/;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BgeGnk/1). Note the use of a regex literal that helps avoid double escaping backslashes.

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[2-9]` - a digit from `2` to `9`
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\s` - a wjitespace
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The word boundaries avoid matching the number as part of another number/word.