# Match exact word with regex using multiple patterns

Tags: regex

I am trying to match an exact word with multiple patterns using regex.

What I tried:

`pattern: "\b(@DOG|@DOG1|@DOG2)\b", text: "@DOG2".`

I want to match exact text `"@DOG2"` using these patterns, and the expected result should be: there is only 1 match `"@DOG2"`. How can I change the pattern text to achieve this?

Interestingly, if I remove all '@' symbol from above text, the regex will work as expected:

`pattern: "\b(DOG|DOG1|DOG2)\b", text: "DOG2".`

Does '@' affect the result? How can I avoid this?

Comment: `\b` is a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324756/5527985), I guess `@` does not belong to *word characters*. If you remove the initial `\b` [it will match (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/XFlVql/1). You could also write [`@(?:DOG|DOG1|DOG2)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/XFlVql/3) in this case.

Comment: ok seems I misunderstood 'word boundary' : )