# How to make sed be aware of the -w flag of git grep?

Tags: bash, git, sed

I thought that with the following code, doing something like `git_grep_sed -w pattern replacement` would match whole words. However, if say, the match is `if`, it will also match the substring in `fifa`. It seems like the `sed` part isn't actually listening to the `-w` flag.

```
git_grep_sed() {
  local grep_options=()
  local search_pattern
  local replacement

  while [[ $1 =~ ^- ]]; do
    grep_options+=("$1")
    shift
  done

  search_pattern=$1
  replacement=$2

  git grep -l "${grep_options[@]}" "$search_pattern" | xargs sed -i "s/$search_pattern/$replacement/g"
}
```

Why is this, and how to fix it? Maybe I have to use something else instead of sed?

Comment: You don't pass the `-w` option to `sed`, so it can't possibly listen to it (and if you did pass it, you'd just get an error because `sed` doesn't have a `-w` option or anything equivalent to it). You'd have to make your function recognize the `-w` option and do something like wrap the pattern in `[[:<:]]\(` and `\)[[:>:]]` to get the equivalent effect. If you want to support other `grep` options, like `-E`, it gets even more complicated.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I don't follow that character class?   All that should be necessary to make a sed match look like `grep -w` is to [surround it with `\b` for word boundary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76830238/sed-regexp-match-only-non-valid-c-identifier-characters-to-rename-a-variable/76856280#76856280)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't give `sed` any flags. And in fact there aren't any that would help. Let's say you have a file like

```
if consistency == "stiff":
    add_water()
```

`git grep -w` will recognise the first line, as it does contain the word `if` by itself, but `sed` will just happily change all `if` instances, because it is unconstrained.

You need to add word boundary anchors to `sed` pattern. Unfortunately, it is not as easy as it seems, because different versions of `sed` do it differently.

```
unset use_osx_sed
if sed -e 's/[[:<:]]//' <<<"" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  use_osx_sed=1
fi


git_grep_sed() {
  local grep_options=()
  local search_pattern
  local sed_search_pattern
  local replacement
  local full_word

  while [[ $1 =~ ^- ]]; do
    grep_options+=("$1")
    if [[ "$1" == -w ]]
    then
      full_word=1
    fi
    shift
  done

  search_pattern="$1"
  sed_search_pattern="$1"
  replacement="$2"

  if [[ -n "$full_word" ]]
  then
    if [[ -n "$use_osx_sed" ]]
    then
      sed_search_pattern="[[:<:]]$search_pattern[[:>:]]"
    else
      sed_search_pattern="\\<$search_pattern\\>"
    fi
  fi

  git grep -l "${grep_options[@]}" "$search_pattern" | xargs sed -i "s/$sed_search_pattern/$replacement/g"
}
```

(The name is probably not accurate. Maybe `non_gnu_sed`? I don't know how far this reaches, I can only test on OSX and Linux...)

Comment: AFAIK OSX uses mostly the BSD versions of tools, so I assume `non_gnu_sed` is actually the better label and the *BSDs’ seds will react similar to OSX’s.

Comment: @Boldewyn I don't know what a non-GNU, non-BSD `sed` would do. E.g. HPUX `sed`. :D Does it even allow word boundaries? No idea, it's been some 33 years since I touched a HPUX. (Also, I'm lazy to rename it :P )

Comment: I tested on NetBSD 10.0_RC3, and both variants work. According to `man re_format` there: "`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match the null string at the beginning and end of a word respectively. ... This is an extension, compatible with but not specified by IEEE Std 1003.2 ("POSIX.2"), and should be used with caution in software intended to be portable to other systems. The additional word delimiters `\<`and `\>` are provided to ease compatibility with traditional SVR4 systems but are not portable and should be avoided." So it seems Linux is following AT&T unix here.

Comment: @stevesliva Surrounding with `\b` is insufficient for a general solution, as I demonstrate in a comment on your answer.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I've been trying to hunt down where `[[:<:]]` is defined as I've seen `[[:<:]]` mentioned in https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html as "The POSIX standard defines [[:<:]] as a start-of-word boundary" but it's not defined in [the POSIX regexp standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) and I can't get it to work with any GNU or POSIX versions of grep, sed, or awk I have access to. Thanks to the big hint in your comment above I finally found it defined as a non-POSIX extension at https://man.netbsd.org/re_format.7. Thanks!

Comment: Than man page is badly misleading, e.g. it says it's for `re_format -- POSIX 1003.2 regular expressions` so it sounds like it's defining POSIX functionality but then goes on to describe a mixture of POSIX and non-POSIX functionality e.g. `a '\' followed by any other character- (matching that character taken as an ordinary character, as if the '\' had not been present-)` - no, POSIX specifically states that's undefined behavior and `there is one new type of atom, a back reference: '\' followed by a non-zero decimal digit d` - no, POSIX does not define backreferences in regexps.

Comment: @Amadan regarding `if sed -e 's/[[:<:]]//' <<<"" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
  use_osx_sed=1
fi` and `if [[ -n "$use_osx_sed" ]]
    then
      sed_search_pattern="[[:<:]]$search_pattern[[:>:]]"
    else
      sed_search_pattern="\\<$search_pattern\\>"
    fi`, rather than mapping that to GNU vs OSK etc, consider just testing what kind of word boundary produces the expected output from some small sample input, then set variables `wbs` to `'[[:<:]]'` or `'\\<'` or `\\b` and `wbe` similarly and then do `sed_search_pattern="$wbs$search_pattern$wbe"`.

Comment: e.g. `if $(sed 's/\bx\b//' <<<'#x#' 2>/dev/null) == "##"; then wbs='\\b'; wbe='\\b'; else if $(sed 's/\<x\>//' <<<'#x#' 2>/dev/null) == "##"; then wbs='\\<'; wbe='\\>'; else if $(sed 's/[[:<:]]x[[:>:]]//' <<<'#x#' 2>/dev/null) == "##"; then wbs='[[:<:]]'; wbe='[[:>:]]'; else echo 'word boundaries not supported' >&2; fi; fi; fi`.

Answer (score 2):

All forms of GNU sed/grep regex, including BRE, include `\b` as a zero-size word boundary character.

All that you should have to do is `s/\bfi\b/newword/` and sed will substitute only the word fi with newword.

In another answer I had some [long discussion of how you might emulate `\b` zero-size match in ERE, PCRE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76830238/sed-regexp-match-only-non-valid-c-identifier-characters-to-rename-a-variable/76856280#76856280)  That's all interesting if you want to learn more complicated regexes.

But, again, *all* GNU sed/grep regex formats support the magic `\b`.

This will highlight only fi:

```
$ grep --color '\bfi\b' <<< "fifa fi"
```

Same as:

```
$ grep -w --color 'fi' <<< "fifa fi"
```

Note: Amadan has a useful usage note that when the 'word' being matched isn't word characters, `grep -w regex` and `grep \bregex\b` are not the same.   That is detailed in the [GNU grep documentation for `-w`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control).   This also highlights to me that, `-w` itself is a GNU grep feature, and not in POSIX grep.  So, `\b` will work in GNU sed, if the pattern is all word characters.  Easy if you're not at some corner case of sed versions or "word."

Comment: These are not equivalent. Compare `grep --color -- '\b-x\b' <<< "z=y-x; set -x"` with `grep -w --color -- '-x' <<< "z=y-x; set -x"`. Here the results are actually _opposite_. Surrounding with `\b` is only equivalent to `-w` if the `-w` search term starts and ends with word characters. (Also, given that `fi` does not include `fifa`, you don't need either strategy, as just `grep --color 'fifa' <<< "fifa fi"` does the same thing. Presumably you meant to search for `fi` in your example, not `fifa`. But again, this is irrelevant for a general case.)

Comment: @EdMorton - me too, now.  I'd thought `\b` was less GNU than `\w`, but it's [mentioned here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/regexp-extensions.html) for sed as BRE/ERE "extension."  [Same for grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html).  And perl, too.  Interesting re: gawk.   Another interesting thing about the GNU lists of extensions is that `\s` is mentioned for sed but not for grep.   I will add GNU sed / GNU grep to answer.

Comment: @EdMorton - also Amadan's note about `-w` highlights two things:   the GNU grep docs do confirm his take, and #2 `-w` is a GNU thing, not a POSIX grep thing, so given GNU grep, seems like GNU sed is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Amadan I am going to delete the `\b` comment from your answer.   Thx for your note.  I added some of the usage nuances to my answer, but the comment is excellent.