# match all except some word

Tags: php, regex

i'm looking for a way, to match all except the some word.

please tell me how i must wrote it?

when i wrote

```
$str = "i am a programmer";
$word = "am";
preg_match_all("/[^($word)]/", $str, $matched);// it do the same, if i when i wrote
preg_match_all("/[^$word]/", $str, $matched);
```

i also tried  `preg_match_all("/[^{$word}]/", $str, $matched);` but it doesn't do the job.

how can i tell **all except that word** ?

Thanks Much

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242698/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list

Comment: What do you want the results to be? An array of letters or a string without the word?

Comment: @Simon I can show on JS, do it?

Comment: @Simon Write what need do with example.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply remove all occurrences of the word?

```
str_replace($word, '', $str);
```

Or split using explode() or preg_split()? This will give you an array with all parts separated by the word.

Comment: i need it to use it in big regex then, so i exactly need to write something like `[^...]` becouse i need to mention `not that word` too.

Comment: Maybe you want to lookaround: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html