# Need to find a regular expression for any word except word1 or word2

Tags: regex

Basically I need a regex which will return true if the string is a word (\w+) EXCEPT if it is the word word1 OR word2.

I've tried many things but dont think I'm even close. Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match all words except a given list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242698/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:word1|word2)$)\w+$
```

should do what you need.

`(?!...)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that ensures that it is not possible to match the enclosed expression at the current position.

Comment: Fantastic, just what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

To match any word that is a sequence of one or more letters, digits or underscores (since you mention you want to match all words using `\w+`) *except* `word1` and `word2` you may use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) solution with [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5HtMU/1). Note that in PostgreSQL regex, `\b` must be replaced with `\y`.

Here are some quick code snippets:

- [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) - `"""\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+""".r.findAllIn(text).toList` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/4YnytP))
- [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy) - `text.findAll(/\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+/)` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/nGPrf0))
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) - `Regex("""\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+""").findAll(text).map{it.value}.toList()` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/kGCNJQ))
- [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) - `select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern '\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file`
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) - `std::regex rx(R"(\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+)"); std::string s = "Extract all words but word1 and word2."; std::vector<std::string> results(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), rx), std::sregex_token_iterator());` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/K4rMaQ))
- [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) - `Dim matches() As String = Regex.Matches(text, "\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToArray()`
- [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) - `extension String {
    func matches(regex: String) -> [String] {
      do {
          let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
          let nsString = self as NSString
          let results = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
          return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range) }
      } catch let error {
          print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          return []
      }
    }
  }
  print("Extract all words but word1 and word2.".matches(regex: #"\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+"#))`
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - `text.match(/\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+/g)` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/1vUXlO))
- [r](/questions/tagged/r) - `regmatches(text, gregexpr("(*UCP)\\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\\b)\\w+", text, perl=TRUE))`  (see [demo](https://ideone.com/QBfoR8)) or `stringr::str_extract_all(text, "\\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\\b)\\w+")` (see [demo](https://rextester.com/ZYNC43355))
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) - `text.scan(/\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+/)` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/UM2Vjv))
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?U)\\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\\b)\\w+"); Matcher m = p.matcher(text); List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(); while(m.find()) { res.add(m.group()); }`  (see [demo](https://ideone.com/5rfjxs))
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) - `if (preg_match_all('~\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+~u', $text, $matches)) { print_r($matches[0]); }`  (see [demo](https://ideone.com/DL2Xeh))
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `re.findall(r"\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+", text)`  (see [demo](https://ideone.com/2ONqDe))
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) - `Regex.Matches(text, @"\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+").Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value)` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/IdmjVH))
- [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) - `grep -oP '\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)\w+' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/LIx0DB))
- [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) - `REGEXP_MATCHES(col, '\y(?!(?:word1|word2)\y)\w+', 'g')` ([demo](https://rextester.com/RLKX79932))
- [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) - `@list = ($str =~ m/\b(?!(?:word1|word2)\b)(\w+)/g);` ([demo](https://ideone.com/HmJ1S8))

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer! Also, good thing you took into account the need for `\b`s

Answer (score 4):

There it is:

```
^(?!word1|word2)\w*
```

Answer (score -11):

Why would you want to use regular expressions for that?

Pseudo-code:

```
return (str != word1 AND str != word2)
```

Comment: Because im using a PHP framework which demands a regex to define the URL. In any case, I cannot use code, only a regex.