# Regex to match all words except a given list (2)

Tags: regex

I already read the popular (28k views) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242698/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list) of this regex. But it doesn't work for me. Better regex has been found, but I am stuck hardly with one little moment.

Here is the list of drinks:

```
whisky/gin/nuka-cola/beer/liqueur/abs-inth/tea
```

and script should get all non soft drinks. I have found nice regex for this:

```
/\b(?!(?:tea|nuka\-cola)\b)[\w\d\-]+\b/
```

And result is:

```
1 : whisky
2 : gin
3 : -cola
4 : beer
5 : liqueur
6 : abs-inth
```

The problem is with the cola (3rd result). This is because \b doesn't like the '-' character. Please, help me to remove this cola from the list.

Comment: I would probably approach it by splitting by the `/`, then using a string search (or regex if you're married to it) to look for "tea" or "cola" and negate those that match in the list of tokens.

Comment: As a quick workaround, add `-cola` to the disallowed drinks.

Comment: @tripleee, and in that case also `cola`.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` matches between alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters, so it matches before and after the dash in `nuka-cola`.

Therefore, you can't use `\b` as a word boundary anchor, but you can define your own. Seeing that your separator is `/`, simply use `(?<=/|^)` as the "start-of-word" anchor, and `(?=/|$)` as the "end-of-word" anchor:

```
/(?<=\/|^)(?!(?:tea|nuka\-cola)(?=\/|$))[\w\d\-]+(?=\/|$)/
```

Of course this assumes you're using a regex engine that supports lookbehind assertions. Unfortunately, you didn't specify which language this is for. JavaScript for example doesn't support lookbehinds.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression should do the trick:

```
(?>[\w-]+)(?<!tea|nuka-cola)
```

Another possibility, if you make sure each keyword starts with a forward slash:

```
/(?!tea|nuka-cola)([\w-]+)
```

If you plan on having more that just two drinks that shouldn't appear in your results, the regex can get ugly quickly. In that case I would have a regex (or a simple loop) that matches every word in the list and check if the matched word is present in a HashSet. If a match is found, I would not include the match in the results.